# What is StackOverflowError in Java ? When it occurs?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Can anybody tell me what is StackOverflowError in Java ?

Comment: give me strength....

Comment: This question surprises me for someone with a rep of 114.

Comment: When you ask too many questions on this site.

Comment: @Mitch: Isn't SO a place for asking questions about programming matters you don't understand?

Comment: @Mitch Seems like a perfectly valid question to me. Admittedly it's pretty basic, but we were all beginners once.

Comment: SO is not "experts only" but it's reasonable to expect people to try and do some searching first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle StackOverflowError in Java ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951635/how-to-handle-stackoverflowerror-in-java)

Comment: So if this is "not a real question", does that mean that knowing what a `StackOverflowError` is isn't useful knowledge? Or that the nature of the `StackOverflowError` can't be known?

Comment: Should have voted to close because this is a clear dupe

Comment: OK, maybe my comment was unjustified, but it seems like a search would quickly answer this question.

Comment: How is this not a real question, it seems legitimate me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A stack overflow occurs when too much data is put on the [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(data_structure)), which is a limited resource.

Here's an example:

```
public class Overflow {
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        main(args);
    }
}
```

That function calls itself repeatedly with no termination condition. Consequently, the stack fills up because each call has to push a return address on the stack, but the return addresses are never popped off the stack because the function never returns, it just keeps calling itself.

Answer (score 9):

There is no such thing as a `StackOverFlowException` in Java.

There is, however, a class named `StackOverflowError` and [the documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html) says:

> Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an application recurses too deeply.

If you don't know what the stack is, read this: [Call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)

Comment: @Don: Don't delete part of my answer please. I've rolled back your deletion.

Comment: I deleted it because I also changed the question so that part of your answer didn't make sense anymore

Comment: why doesnt an error happens when i make an infinite loop with  a new object creation.

Answer (score 4):

Each time you call a function, a small piece of a special memory region - the stack - is allocated to it and holds the local variables and the context of the function. If our function calls another function, the next piece is cut off the stack and so on. The stack shrinks when a function returns again. If the nesting level becomes too high, it can overflow.

This is a very general concept. On Java, a `StackOverflowError` is thrown when the stack size is exceeded. This is an **error**, not an **exception**, because you are urged to avoid this situation, not recover from it.

The typical example would be endless recursion:

```
public void foo(int i) {
  return foo(i+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when recursive method is being called too many times. For example:

```
public void doSomething(int time)
{
  System.out.println("do #" + (doSomething(time++)));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The Java machine allocates your program a specific quantity of memory. The error is caused by your program using too much memory. The examples above are good, but if you are trying to create a very large array that can cause it to overflow as well.
You can Allocate more memory(this example of 200MB) to your program by using command line arguments

```
java -Xmx200m YOUR_PROGRAM_CLASS
```

This will decrease the chance of you getting a StackOverFlowException.

[This Explains the command line options](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html#Xms)

(http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html#Xms)

Comment: -1: StackOverflowError can occur even if there is lot of heap memory

Comment: however the root cause of the error is still the same, too much memory. you can either solve it by increasing the heap size or changing your program to use the memory more effectively.