# How to avoid the 1024 lines of Java exception stack limit

Tags: java

I ran into a Java StackOverflow error, but the offending recursive call is so deep, that it does not give me the full stack trace. It only dumps out the first 1024 lines of methods of the StackOverflow exception.

How can I get the full stack trace, so that I can know the root cause?

Comment: Not an answer, but consider also debugging with breakpoints, logging, etc.

Comment: The root cause is in the first lines, the rest should look the same. Could you try to post the stacktrace to have a look at it? ( probably in pastebin.com or something like that? )

Comment: Are you using recursion by any chance? If so, this helps  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/01/07/9286576.aspx . See the related discussion on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951635/how-to-handle-stackoverflowerror-in-java

Comment: I would bet this is impossible. It might very well be so that the jvm intentionally has a limit on the number of stack frames to reify on exceptions. Otherwise the time complexity for throwing exceptions would be linear in the number of stack frames.

Answer (score 21):

The switch `-XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth` allows larger and smaller stack trace lengths. Set it to `-1` for an unlimited length. E.g.:

```
-XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=-1
```

Comment: With recent Java versions this doesn't work: MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=-1 is outside the allowed range [ 0 ... 1073741823 ]

Comment: Which version did you test on @paj28 ?

Comment: It was on 10.0.2

Comment: Does not work on 16.

Comment: Where does this go??

Comment: Ohh if you're using a wildfly/jboss server it goes in standalone.conf

Answer (score 2):

You can use -Xss to change the stack size, but it won't help if you have unbounded recursion.  It sounds like your stopping condition might not be worked out.

Comment: If anything, *lower* the stack size so the exception happens sooner and the stacktrace fits within the lines allowed! :-)

Answer (score -1):

Print the stack manually, the limit put on e.printStackTrace() does not apply when you provide a writer (might need to quote me on that but I've never experienced it being cropped when using this method).

Here is some easy code that I employ to get full traces:

```
/**
 * Produces a Java-like stack trace string.
 * 
 * @param e
 * @return
 */
public static String exceptionStack(Throwable e) {
    final Writer result = new StringWriter();
    final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(result);
    e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I have only 1024 lines, it doesn't show the root cause.