# Using continuation / CPS to implement tail-recursive MergeSort in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, continuation-passing

I am trying to implement a `tail-recursive` `MergeSort` in `OCaml`.

Since `Mergesort` naturally is not tail-recursive, so I am using `CPS` to implement it.

Also my implementation is inspired by [Tail-recursive merge sort in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529580/tail-recursive-merge-sort-in-ocaml)

**Below is my code**

---

```
let merge compare_fun l1 l2 = 
  let rec mg l1 l2 acc =
    match l1, l2 with
      | ([], []) -> List.rev acc
      | ([], hd2::tl2) -> mg [] tl2 (hd2::acc)
      | (hd1::tl1, []) -> mg tl1 [] (hd1::acc)
      | (hd1::tl1, hd2::tl2) ->
         let c = compare_fun hd1 hd2
         in 
         if c = 1 then mg l1 tl2 (hd2::acc)
         else if c = 0 then mg tl1 tl2 (hd2::hd1::acc)
         else mg tl1 l2 (hd1::acc)
  in 
  mg l1 l2 [];;

let split_list p l = 
  let rec split_list p (acc1, acc2) = function
    | [] -> (List.rev acc1, List.rev acc2)
    | hd::tl ->
      if p > 0 then split_list (p-1) (hd::acc1, acc2) tl
      else split_list (p-2) (acc1, hd::acc2) tl
  in 
  split_list p ([], []) l;;

let mergeSort_cps compare_fun l =
  let rec sort_cps l cf =  (*cf = continuation func*)
    match l with 
      | [] -> cf []
      | hd::[] -> cf [hd]
      | _ ->
        let (left, right) = split_list ((List.length l)/2) l
        in 
        sort_cps left (fun leftR -> sort_cps right (fun rightR -> cf (merge compare_fun leftR rightR)))
  in 
  sort_cps l (fun x -> x);;
```

---

When I compile it, and run it with a `1,000,000` `integers`, it gives the error of `stackoverflow`. **Why?**

---

**Edit**

Here is the code I used for testing:

```
let compare_int x y =
  if x > y then 1
  else if x = y then 0
  else -1;;

let create_list n = 
  Random.self_init ();
  let rec create n' acc =
    if n' = 0 then acc
    else 
      create (n'-1) ((Random.int (n/2))::acc)
  in 
  create n [];;

let l = create_list 1000000;;

let sl = mergeSort_cps compare_int l;;
```

in `http://try.ocamlpro.com/`, it gave this error: `Exception: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.`

in `local ocaml top level`, it didn't have any problem

Comment: I can't reproduce your reported behavior. When I try your code on a list of 1,000,000 ints, it sorts them properly. It works for me in the toplevel and in compiled code.

Comment: Tried your code with 10,000,000 ints, with both ocamlc and ocamlopt in i386 (32bits) with the default stack setting. No stackoverflow. Double check your build and if it reproduces, please clarify your environment.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I tried my code in http://try.ocamlpro.com/, it gives such an error. I guess it is a bug in the site.

Comment: I don't know the details of that site, but it's very difficult to get proper tail calls in many virtual machine language environments (JavaScript, Java, etc.). Very possibly the site you used is translating OCaml to JavaScript or similar. If you want to get deep into OCaml you probably should use the INRIA release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding another answer to make a separate point: it seems that much of the confusion among answerers is caused by the fact that you don't use the standard OCaml compiler, but the TryOCaml website which runs a distinct OCaml backend, on top of javascript, and has therefore slightly different optimization and runtime characteristics.

I can reliably reproduce the fact that, on the [TryOCaml website](http://try.ocamlpro.com/), the CPS-style function `mergeSort_cps` you show fails on lists of length `1_000_000` with the following error:

```
Exception: InternalError: too much recursion.
```

My analysis is that this is *not* due to a lack of tail-rec-ness, but by a lack of support, on the Javascript backend, of the non-obvious way in which the CPS-translated call is tailrec: recursion goes through a lambda-abstraction boundary (but still in tail position).

Turning the code in the *direct*, non-tail-rec version makes the problem go away:

```
let rec merge_sort compare = function
  | [] -> []
  | [hd] -> [hd]
  | l ->
    let (left, right) = split_list (List.length l / 2) l in
    merge compare (merge_sort compare left) (merge_sort compare right);;
```

As I said in my other answer, this code has a logarithmic stack depth, so no StackOverflow will arise from its use (tail-rec is not everything). It is simpler code that the Javascript backend handles better.

Note that you can make it noticeably faster by using a better implementation `split` (still with your definition of `merge`) that avoids the double traversal of `List.length` then splitting:

```
let split li =
  let rec split ls rs = function
    | [] -> (ls, rs)
    | x::xs -> split rs (x::ls) xs in
  split [] [] li;;

let rec merge_sort compare = function
  | [] -> []
  | [hd] -> [hd]
  | l ->
    let (left, right) = split l in
    merge compare (merge_sort compare left) (merge_sort compare right);;
```

Comment: could you please further explain the new `split` function? I don't really understand how it works.

Comment: @JacksonTale I suggest you get a pen and paper and execute `split [] [] [1;2;3]` by hand.

Comment: ok, your version of `split` doesn't care about the order of the elements and doesn't care about the order of `left` or `right` lists, but anyway it suits for mergesort because mergesort just merge two lists and don't care for those things, right? if we need a `split_list` which just cut a list in the middle, then your version won't suit

Comment: can I know `List.length` will have `O(n)` or just `O(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Reading the comments, it seems that your `Stack_overflow` error is hard to reproduce.

Nevertheless, your code is not entirely in CPS or tail-recursive: in `merge_sort`, the  calls to `split_list` and `merge` are made in a non-tail-call position.

The question is: by making your CPS transform and generous use of accumulators, what will be the worst stack depth related to recursion? Saving stack depth on the `sort` calls is in fact not very interesting: as each split the list in two, the worst stack depth would be `O(log n)` for `n` the size the input list.

On the contrary, `split` and `merge` would have made a linear `O(n)` usage of the stack if they weren't written in accumulator-passing style, so they are important to make tail-rec. As your implementation of those routines is tail-rec, there should be no need to worry about stack usage, and neither to convert the sort routine itself in CPS form that makes the code harder to read.

(Note that this logarithmic-decrease argument is specific to mergesort. A quicksort can have linear stack usage in worst case, so it could be important to make it tail-rec.)

Comment: I tried my code in http://try.ocamlpro.com/, it gives such an error. I guess it is a bug in the site.

Comment: I think my `split_list` and `merge` are tail-recursive.

Comment: Yes they are, but they are used in non-tail positions inside the `sort` routine, so you would still have to worry if, say, either called `sort` recursively (which isn't the case here).

Comment: how can I transform the whole code so they are used in tail positions inside `sort` routine, so I have `100% pure tail recursive`?

Comment: @JacksonTale are you sure this will solve your problem? I suspect you're wrong and the bug is somewhere else, for example in the way you build the input you pass to the sorting function. Can you show the complete code your test?

Comment: thanks. I just guess it is the problem of http://try.ocamlpro.com. I used exactly the same code, one for try.ocamlpro.com, one locally in ocaml top leve. top level didn't have problem, but try.ocamlpro.com had