# Increase stack size when compiling with mingw?

Tags: c++, stack-overflow, stack, mingw, callstack

I'm writing a recursive flood-fill algorithm to find connected components in an image, my code compiles and runs well with MSVC 2008 compiler; but the mingw-compiled binary crashed at runtime.

After I converted the algorithm to non-recursive with std::stack, everything goes well.

But what if I must use recursive algorithm in some case, and mingw cannot handle it?

How can I increased stack size of a binary, is there any compilation options?

Thanks

Comment: Also: Use a *scanline* flood fill. It usually doesn't require that much stack space. Also: Use your own stack and make your function iterative.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use

```
gcc -Wl,--stack,N
```

where N is stack size. E.g. `gcc -Wl,--stack,4194304`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe increasing stack size is not the solution you want. These restrictions do exist for a reason.
It also may happen that in a near future your algorithm will use even more stack space and you will have to increase it again.

Perhaps you should consider converting your algorithm into a non-recursive one.
This can be done for every algorithm.
[See this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931762/can-every-recursion-be-converted-into-iteration)

And you will probably gain a performance improvement also

Answer (score 0):

probably the best bet is to use `pthreads` to start a new thread and run your algorithm in the new thread. One of the parameters to `pthread_create` is `pthread_attr_t`. Using this attribute you can specify the stack size (by calling `pthread_attr_setstacksize`).

**Edit:** Whether this works or not is dependent on support of the underlying compatibility layer