# C error: size of array is too large

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, int, limits

I have tried to compile this C code:

```
#define MAX_INT 2147483647

int main()
{
   int vector[MAX_INT];
   return 0;
}
```

I'm using the C compilers provided by both MinGW and MSYS projects, i.e., MinGW / MSYS. MinGW compiler is "gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)", which is the most recently version and have win32 thread model, and MSYS compiler is "gcc version 3.4.4 (msys special)" with posix thread model.

That MAX_INT constant value is set in the constant "__INT_MAX__" provided by the "limits.h" header.

How can I avoid this problem and get my simplest code compiled?

Comment: That's 8 gigabytes worth of `int`s. Do you compile for 64 bits? Do you have 8 gb of RAM? Then try to `malloc` it, since it surely won't fit on stack.

Comment: Might I ask: what do you intend to do with all those ints?

Comment: No. I don't  have that amount of memory. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Bathsheba I'm trying to build the OpenSSH source.

Comment: @GracoBabeuf And how exactly the code above is helping you in building OpenSSH?

Comment: @EugeneSh. That constant value is set to a variable present in OpenSSH source.

Comment: What constant and why do you think you need this array? I can guarantee that compiling OpenSSH does not require allocating 8gb on stack.

Comment: @EugeneSh. This value, 2147483647 = 8GB, is setted to the constant IOV_MAX in the "atomicio.c" code.

Comment: So what? Why do you need an array of this size?

Comment: I don't know yet.

Comment: Then you don't need it. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stack will not be that large to contain the array this is the main problem.
Try setting the stack size using the following lines as suggested in [Increase stack size when compiling with mingw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557691/increase-stack-size-when-compiling-with-mingw) while compiling

```
gcc -Wl,--stack,N
where N is stack size. E.g. gcc -Wl,--stack,4194304
```

Also as mentioned in the comments you might have to compile for 64 bits and      will require that much amount of RAM or possibly a large page file.