# How to deal with the small stack size in MinGW?

Tags: c, memory, mingw

I have the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#define arraySize 5
#define arraySize 500
void func(double B[arraySize][arraySize])
{
    B[0][0] = 5;
}

int main(void) {
    double Ar2D[arraySize][arraySize];
    func(Ar2D);
    printf("%f", Ar2D[0][0]);
}
```

Code works fine when I test it in a linux virtual machine, but when I run it in minGW, it crashes if I set arraySize to 500 (works fine in minGW if I set arraySize to 5). What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: Do not put the array in stack, that's the way. Easy alternative: Make it global variable, since size is compile time constant.

Comment: The default stack size on Linux is 8Mib and on Windows it's only 1Mib if I remember correctly. Best is not using huge local variables. Either make it static or global.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase stack size when compiling with mingw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557691/increase-stack-size-when-compiling-with-mingw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should avoid using the stack for large things.

It's also a security risk as stack overflows wan be abused by hackers (e.g. to try to attempt running arbitrary code).

Better is to use the heap, you can do this by replacing

```c
double Ar2D[arraySize][arraySize];
```

with

```c
double** Ar2D = (double**)malloc(arraySize * arraySize * sizeof(double));
```

and of course don't forget to `free(Ar2D);`