# How to print all the Permutations of array elements efficienctly with minimum code

Tags: c, algorithm, permutation, combinatorics

We have an array, `int array={1,2,3};` 
Display all the possible permutations which will be

```
{1,3,2} ,
{2,1,3} , 
{2,3,1} , 
{3,1,2} , 
{3,2,1} etc.
```

all `n!` possibilities.

I know both ways direct recursive and backtracking too.
Is there any better way to do the same ? 
Thank You.

Comment: Is there a problem if you use STL library of c++ ?

Comment: Thanks . Oh ! Needed that badly as I wanted to solve another problem using this concept. Okay will try to use normal recursion.

Comment: If you want an iterative approach you can see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716847/converting-recursive-permutation-generator-to-iterative

Comment: Thanks for that again but Iterative approach was not I have asked for.

Comment: What are you asking actually ?
can you describe please...

Comment: what did you mean by minimum code ?
does that mean minimum length of code ?
then why don't you use C++..?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the methods described [here](http://www.bearcave.com/random_hacks/permute.html).

You can modify his algo slightly for your need:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void print(const int *v, const int size)
{
  if (v != 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      printf("%c", i ? ',':'{');
      printf("%d", v[i] );
    }
    printf("}\n");
  }
} // print


void permute(int *v, const int start, const int n)
{  
  if (start == n-1) {
    print(v, n);
  }
  else {
    for (int i = start; i < n; i++) {
      int tmp = v[i];

      v[i] = v[start];
      v[start] = tmp;
      permute(v, start+1, n);
      v[start] = v[i];
      v[i] = tmp;
    }
  }
}


int main(void)
{
  int v[] = {1, 2, 3};
  permute(v, 0, sizeof(v)/sizeof(int));
}
```

[Live example here](http://ideone.com/33yUm7)

As described in other answer, C++ stl library provides an implmentation of `next_permutation`. You can peep inside stl code and make necessary changes to port it to `C` code.

Comment: Yes thank you.I still do't have a 15 point so won't be able to +1 , but I Started with the same code as above but what I want is that  whether possible to reduce it?  or is there exists any declarative way to the same In C or at least an algo overview of the same.

Comment: @Pushpa Try to understand the logic behind the code and try to reduce it by making 1 change each time and recompile and verify the result. You should be able to reduce it to your requirements in some time.