# Create faster Fibonacci function for n > 100 in MATLAB / octave

Tags: matlab, octave, fibonacci, number-theory

I have a function that tells me the nth number in a Fibonacci sequence.  The problem is it becomes very slow when trying to find larger numbers in the Fibonacci sequence does anyone know how I can fix this?

```
function f = rtfib(n)
 if (n==1)
     f= 1;
 elseif (n == 2)
     f = 2;
 else
     f =rtfib(n-1) + rtfib(n-2);   
 end
```

The Results,

```
tic; rtfib(20), toc
ans =  10946
Elapsed time is 0.134947 seconds.

tic; rtfib(30), toc
ans =  1346269
Elapsed time is 16.6724 seconds.
```

I can't even get a value after 5 mins doing `rtfib(100)`

PS: I'm using octave 3.8.1

Comment: Write an iterative solution, rather than a recursive solution.

Comment: It might be faster when you avoid the rekursive call but use an array instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9122277/97160

Comment: If the function must only output the nth term, not the first n terms of the sequence, you can do it in θ(log(n)) complexity with recursive doubling. [Max's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26835017/2541573) hints at such a solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If **time** is important (not programming techniques):

```
function f = fib(n)
if (n == 1)
   f = 1;
elseif (n == 2)
   f = 2;
else
   fOld = 2;
   fOlder = 1;
   for i = 3 : n
     f = fOld + fOlder;
     fOlder = fOld;
     fOld = f;
   end
end
end
```

`tic;fib(40);toc; ans = 165580141; Elapsed time is 0.000086 seconds.`

You could even use `uint64`. `n = 92` is the most you can get from `uint64`:

`tic;fib(92);toc; ans = 12200160415121876738; Elapsed time is 0.001409 seconds.`

Because,

`fib(93) = 19740274219868223167 > intmax('uint64') =  18446744073709551615`

## Edit

In order to get `fib(n)` up to `n = 183`, It is possible to **use two uint64 as one number**,

with a special function for summation,

```
function [] = fib(n)
fL = uint64(0);
fH = uint64(0);
MaxNum = uint64(1e19);
if (n == 1)
   fL = 1;
elseif (n == 2)
   fL = 2;
else   
   fOldH = uint64(0);
   fOlderH = uint64(0);
   fOldL = uint64(2);
   fOlderL = uint64(1);
   for i = 3 : n
      [fL q] = LongSum (fOldL , fOlderL , MaxNum);
      fH = fOldH + fOlderH + q;
      fOlderL = fOldL;
      fOlderH = fOldH;
      fOldL = fL;
      fOldH = fH;
   end
 end
 sprintf('%u',fH,fL)
 end
```

`LongSum` is:

```
function [s q] = LongSum (a, b, MaxNum)
if a + b >= MaxNum
   q = 1;
   if a >= MaxNum
      s = a - MaxNum;
      s = s + b;
   elseif b >= MaxNum
      s = b - MaxNum;
      s = s + a;
   else
      s = MaxNum - a;
      s = b - s;
   end
else
   q = 0;
   s = a + b;
end
```

**Note** some complications in `LongSum` might seem unnecessary, but they are not!

(All the deal with inner `if` is that I wanted to avoid `s = a + b - MaxNum` in one command, because it might overflow and store an irrelevant number in `s`)

*Results*

`tic;fib(159);toc; Elapsed time is 0.009631 seconds.`

`ans = 1226132595394188293000174702095995`

`tic;fib(183);toc;` **Elapsed time is 0.009735 seconds.**

**fib(183) = 127127879743834334146972278486287885163**

However, you have to be careful about `sprintf`.

I also did it with three uint64, and I could get up to,

`tic;fib(274);toc;` **Elapsed time is 0.032249 seconds.**

**ans = 1324695516964754142521850507284930515811378128425638237225**

(It's pretty much the same code, but I could share it if you are interested).

**Note** that we have `fib(1) = 1 , fib(2) = 2`according to question, while it is more common with `fib(1) = 1 , fib(2) = 1`, first 300 fibs are listed [here](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibtable.html) (thanks to @Rick T).

Comment: Thanks!!! Very Fast!!!
For those who may use this in the future.  Please note the sequence of fib numbers is off by one when checked against a list of fibonacci numbers
http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibtable.html

Comment: I think you can use [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725-variable-precision-integer-arithmetic) too for large sums.

Comment: @Amro, because we started with `fib(1) = 1` and `fib(2) = 2`, (according to question), while it's more common with `fib(1) = 1` and `fib(2) = 1`.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like fibonaacci series follows the **[`golden ratio`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)**, as talked about in some detail [**`here`**](http://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/fibonacci-sequence.html).

This was used in [this MATLAB File-exchange code](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29991-vectorized-fibonacci/content//fibonacci.m) and I am writing here, just the esssence of it -

```
sqrt5 = sqrt(5);
alpha = (1 + sqrt5)/2;   %// alpha = 1.618... is the golden ratio
fibs  = round( alpha.^n ./ sqrt5 )
```

You can feed an integer into `n` for the `nth` number in `Fibonacci Series` or feed an array `1:n` to have the whole series.

Please note that this method holds good till `n = 69` only.

Comment: nice about the connection of `fib` and `golden ratio`.

Comment: Does this approach maintain accuracy as `n` increases in magnitude?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth You are right about that! Thank you on pointing out that. So, I have checked with `vpa` and it's good till `69` only.

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to the Symbolic Math Toolbox in MATLAB, you could always [just](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/evalin.html) [call](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/call-built-in-mupad-functions-from-the-matlab-command-window.html) the Fibonacci function from [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/numlib-fibonacci.html):

```
>> fib = @(n) evalin(symengine, ['numlib::fibonacci(' num2str(n) ')'])
>> fib(274)
ans =
818706854228831001753880637535093596811413714795418360007
```

It is pretty fast:

```
>> timeit(@() fib(274))
ans =
    0.0011
```

---

Plus you can you go for as large numbers as you want (limited only by how much RAM you have!), it is still blazing fast:

```
% see if you can beat that!
>> tic
>> x = fib(100000);
>> toc               % Elapsed time is 0.004621 seconds.

% result has more than 20 thousand digits!
>> length(char(x))   % 20899
```

Here is the full value of `fib(100000)`: http://pastebin.com/f6KPGKBg

Comment: some related readings: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52677.html, http://www.catonmat.net/blog/on-the-linear-time-algorithm-for-finding-fibonacci-numbers/

Comment: highly recommended: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34766-the-fibonacci-sequence (really anything by *John D'Errico* you know is high quality!)

Answer (score 2):

To reach large numbers you can use symbolic computation. The following works in Matlab R2010b.

```
syms x y %// declare variables
z = x + y;  %// define formula
xval = '0'; %// initiallize x, y values
yval = '1'; 
for n = 2:300
    zval = subs(z, [x y], {xval yval}); %// update z value
    disp(['Iteration ' num2str(n) ':'])
    disp(zval)
    xval = yval; %// shift values
    yval = zval;
end
```

Comment: I would love to try this out but the symbols package in octave isn't really compatible with matlab code yet.  It gives errors with syms x y

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in O(log n) time with matrix exponentiation:

```
X = [0 1
     1 1]
```

X^n will give you the nth fibonacci number in the lower right-hand corner; X^n can be represented as the product of several matrices X^(2^i), so for example X^11 would be X^1 * X^2 * X^8, i <= log_2(n). And X^8 = (X^4)^2, etc, so at most 2*log(n) matrix multiplications.

Answer (score 1):

One performance issue is that you use a recursive solution. Going for an iterative method will spare you of the argument passing for each function call. As Olivier pointed out, it will reduce the complexity to linear.

You can also look **[here](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html#formula)**. Apparently there's a formula that computes the n'th member of the Fibonacci sequence. I tested it for up to 50'th element. **For higher n values it's not very accurate.**

Comment: It's way more than just saving the argument passing; it reduces the time complexity from exponential to linear.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of a fast Fibonacci computation in Python could be as follows. I know this is Python not MATLAB/Octave, however it might be helpful.

Basically, rather than calling the same Fibonacci function over and over again with O(2<sup>n</sup>), we are storing Fibonacci sequence on a list/array with O(n):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5

class Fib:
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.n=n
        self.fibList=[None]*(self.n+1)
        self.populateFibList()
    def populateFibList(self):
        for i in range(len(self.fibList)):
            if i==0:
                self.fibList[i]=0
            if i==1:
                self.fibList[i]=1
            if i>1:
                self.fibList[i]=self.fibList[i-1]+self.fibList[i-2]
    def getFib(self):
        print('Fibonacci sequence up to ', self.n, ' is:')
        for i in range(len(self.fibList)):
            print(i, ' : ', self.fibList[i])
        return self.fibList[self.n]

def isNonnegativeInt(value):
    try:
        if int(value)>=0:#throws an exception if non-convertible to int: returns False
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except:
        return False

n=input('Please enter a non-negative integer: ')

while isNonnegativeInt(n)==False:
    n=input('A non-negative integer is needed: ')

n=int(n) # convert string to int

print('We are using ', n, 'based on what you entered')

print('Fibonacci result is ', Fib(n).getFib())
```

Output for `n=12` would be like:

[image]

I tested the runtime for `n=100`, `300`, `1000` and the code is really fast, I don't even have to wait for the output.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to speed up the recursive implementation of a Fibonacci function is to realize that, substituting `f(n-1)` by its definition,

```
f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)
     = f(n-2) + f(n-3) + f(n-2)
     = 2*f(n-2) + f(n-3)
```

This simple transformation greatly reduces the number of steps taken to compute a number in the series.

If we start with OP's code, slightly corrected:

```
function result = fibonacci(n)
switch n
case 0
   result = 0;
case 1
   result = 1;
case 2
   result = 1;
case 3
   result = 2;
otherwise
   result = fibonacci(n-2) + fibonacci(n-1);
end
```

And apply our transformation:

```
function result = fibonacci_fast(n)
switch n
case 0
   result = 0;
case 1
   result = 1;
case 2
   result = 1;
case 3
   result = 2;
otherwise
   result = fibonacci_fast(n-3) + 2*fibonacci_fast(n-2);
end
```

Then we see a 30x speed improvement for computing the 20th number in the series (using Octave):

```
>> tic; for ii=1:100, fibonacci(20); end; toc
Elapsed time is 12.4393 seconds.
>> tic; for ii=1:100, fibonacci_fast(20); end; toc
Elapsed time is 0.448623 seconds.
```

Of course [Rashid's non-recursive implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26829539/7328782) is another 60x faster still: 0.00706792 seconds.