# vectorizing function in octave / matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a function that I was wondering if it was possible to vectorize it and not have to use a for loop.  The code is below.

```
a=1:2:8
for jj=1:length(a)
     b(jj)=rtfib(a(jj)); %fibbonacci function
end
b
```

output below:

```
a =

   1   3   5   7

>>>b =

    1    3    8   21
```

I was trying to do it this way

```
t = 0:.01:10;
y = sin(t);
```

but doing the code below doesn't work any suggestions?
ps: I'm trying to keep the function **rtfib** because of it's speed and I need to use very large Fibonacci numbers. I'm using octave 3.8.1

```
 a=1:2:8
 b=rtfib(a)
```

Here's the rtfib code below as requested

```
function f = rtfib(n)

if (n == 0)
    f = 0;
elseif (n==1)
    f=1;
elseif (n == 2)
    f = 2;
else
    fOld = 2;
    fOlder = 1;
    for i = 3 : n
        f = fOld + fOlder;
        fOlder = fOld;
        fOld = f;
    end
end
end
```

Comment: This probably depends on your `rtfib` function. Can you post the code? But also, you'll probably get as good a speedup (if you're in a reasonably current release of Matlab) by just preallocating `b`, i.e. before you loop type `b=zeros(size(a))`. Loops aren't that slow anymore

Comment: @Dan sure, I've added the rtfib code to the question I'm using octave 3.8.1 so it's not as fast as matlab yet

Comment: Don't mind the vectorization, but instead of the double for-loop you could just use the single for loop of rtfib to save the whole vector! Linear instead of quadratic runtime!

Comment: For all SO users visiting this post, the OP and subsequent people who provided an answer had a very nice discussion on creating the Fibonacci sequence efficiently and quickly.  That code seen in the post above was from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829209/create-faster-fibonacci-function-for-n-100-in-matlab-octave

Answer (score 0):

You can see that your function `rtfib` actually computes every Fibonacci number up to `n`.
You can modify it so that is stores and returns all these number, so that you only have to call the function once with the maximum number you need:

```
function f = rtfib(n)

    f=zeros(1,n+1);
    if (n >= 0)
        f(1) = 0;
    end
    if (n>=1)
        f(2)=1;
    end
    if (n >= 2)
        f(3) = 2;
    end
    if n>2
        fOld = 2;
        fOlder = 1;
        for i = 3 : n
            f(i+1) = fOld + fOlder;
            fOlder = fOld;
            fOld = f(i+1);
        end
    end
end
```

(It will return fibonnaci(n) in f(n+1), if you don't need the 0 you could change it so that it returns fibonnaci(n) in f(n) if you prefer)

Then you only need to call

```
>>f=rtfib(max(a));
>>b=f(a+1)
b =

 1     3     8    21
```

If you don't want to store everything you could modify the function `rtfib` a little more, so that it takes the the array `a` as input, compute the Fibonacci numbers up to `max(a)` but only stores the one needed, and it would directly return `b`.
Both solutions will slow down `rtfib` itself but it will be a lot faster than calculating the Fibonacci numbers from 0 each time.