# Rewrite the definition in order to avoid the recursive call

Tags: prolog

Given the following PROLOG predicate definition f(integer, integer), with the flow model (i,
o):

```
f(0, -1) :- !.
f(I,Y):-
  J is I-1,
  f(J,V),
  V > 0,
  !,
  K is J,
  Y is K+V.
f(I,Y):-
  J is I-1,
  f(J,V),
  Y is V+I.
```

Rewrite the definition in order to avoid the recursive call f(J,V) in both clauses. Do NOT redefine
the predicate. Justify your answer

Comment: How far did you get in your attempts? Have you found out what the predicate `f` describes? That's probably the first step.

Comment: Have you tried running it to see what the output is? Then you can reverse engineer the output back into code instead of trying to do it mentally by staring at code all day.

Comment: this is an example of exercise for my exam,i cannot use the pc for solving this type of exercises during the exam.

Comment: Then make a table of input values, run the code by hand and record the output. That will give you some idea of what the code is doing. This is obviously written to be hard to keep track of mentally. Also give the variable names something more meaningful like count_down, count_up, increment, counter, halt_value, etc.

Comment: To bad you can not use OEIS. ([ref](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C4%2C7%2C11%2C16&sort=&language=english&go=Search))

Answer (score -1):

With inspiration from [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122277/what-is-a-non-recursive-solution-for-fibonacci-like-sequence-in-java):

```
ffast(0, -1) :- !.
ffast(1, 0) :- !.
ffast(2, 2) :- !.
ffast(X, Y) :-
    X0 is X - 1,
    ffast(X0, Y0),
    Y is Y0 + X0.
```

... and then to:

```
ffast2(0, Y) :- !, Y = -1.
ffast2(1, Y) :- !, Y = 0.
ffast2(X, Y) :- Y is ((X * (X - 1)) / 2) + 1.
```

(Guarding against Y being an input, as per best-practices.)

Comment: I used `N is N0 - 1, R is (N * (N + 1) / 2) + 1` which I found on OEIS.