# How to Iterate through all nodes of a treeView Control. C#

Tags: c#, loops, treeview, nodes

I am selecting all controls I have in a `form`

if controls are `Treeviews`, I'll iterate all nodes they have

I need something like:
(And it is my code)

```
foreach (Control c in PanelSM.Controls)
{
    if (c is TreeView) 
    {    
        TreeNodeCollection myNodes = c.Nodes;//<<<<< Here is a mistake
        foreach (TreeNode n in myNodes)
        {
            String text = rm.GetString(n.Name);
            //And more things
            //...
            //...
            //...
       }
    }
    //...
}
```

**Any idea?**

Thank You

Comment: Ahhhh.. Sorry.  My bad.

Comment: wait... is all that you are needing `((TreeView)c).Nodes`?

Comment: [Does this help ?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwc698z7%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: I saw it @ Sriram Sakthivel. The problem is: I can't do it: TreeNodeCollection myNodes = c.Nodes;//<<<<< Here **was** the mistake

Comment: @Darren Kopp OMFG! It was very easy. **Thank You so much!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that `c` is actually a variable of type `Control`, which does not have a **Nodes** member. You will need it to cast it as a `TreeView` type.

You can do either of these two approaches:

```
if (c is TreeView) 
{
    TreeNodeCollection myNodes = ((TreeView) c).Nodes; // <<--- Note the cast
    ...
}
```

or

```
TreeView tv = c as TreeView;
if (tv != null)
{
        TreeNodeCollection myNodes = tv.Nodes;
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 40):

You need to use recursion. A method like this should suffice

```
IEnumerable<TreeNode> Collect(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    foreach(TreeNode node in nodes)
    {
        yield return node;

        foreach (var child in Collect(node.Nodes))
            yield return child;
    }
}
```

Then in your method you can just do

```
 foreach (var node in Collect(tree.Nodes))
 {
     // you will see every child node here
 }
```

Comment: Hey @Darren Kopp Thank You so much! **You rule!**

Answer (score 11):

It's pretty easy:

```
void TraverseTree(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    foreach (var child in nodes)
    {
        DoSomethingWithNode(child);
        TraverseTree(child.Nodes);
    }
}
```

And call it with:

```
TraverseTree(MyTreeView.Nodes);
```

Comment: This answer worked for me in asp.net. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I prefer simplicity, and here is my simple solution:

```
    protected void TraverseNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes, string action, int maxDepth = 2) 
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
        {
            if (node.ChildNodes.Count > 0 && node.Depth < maxDepth)
                TraverseNodes(node.ChildNodes, action, maxDepth);

            //do something!!!
            var x = node.Text;
            node.Checked = !node.Checked;
        }
    }
```

I decided to include a "maximum depth" as a bonus, so enjoy.

Call it as follows:

```
                TraverseNodes(this.Activities.Nodes, "");
```

Unlike some of the examples posted here, I actually tested this (ouch! I can hear them say).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    foreach (TreeNode t in tvMenu.Nodes)
    {
        for (int iParent = 0; iParent < t.ChildNodes.Count; iParent++)
        {
            for (int iChild = 0; iChild < t.ChildNodes[iParent].ChildNodes.Count; iChild++)
            {
                if (t.ChildNodes[iParent].ChildNodes[iChild].Text == "")
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of Darren's great answer, you can combine **recursion and class extension**.

Declare somewhere in your namespace :

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TreeNode> All( this TreeNodeCollection nodes )
    {
        foreach( TreeNode n in nodes )
        {
            yield return n;
            foreach( TreeNode child in n.Nodes.All( ) )
                yield return child;
        }
    }
}
```

Note the "this" before the first argument of the method.

Then you can use this new method in all treeviews as:

```
foreach( TreeNode n in myTreeview.Nodes.All() ) ...
```

Comment: You can make most any method an extension method.  It's not really adding anything to the answer to just turn it into an extension method here.  On top of that [you didn't choose a particularly good implementation for traversing the tree to begin with](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10253591/1159478).