# Key cannot be found in nodes

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, containskey

It is my understanding that the NAME of a node in a TreeView is the same as the KEY.
If so, I don't understand why `ContainsKey` (fyi: `ContainsKey` requires string) does not return the correct result:

```
MessageBox.Show(tv_Projects.SelectedNode.Name); //This shows "1"
MessageBox.Show(tv_Projects.Nodes.ContainsKey("1").ToString()); //This shows "false"
```

Why does the second message box say "false" when the key "1" clearly exists, as stated in the first message box.
This is how I create the node.

```
TreeNode Approved;
TreeNode Approved_Open;
Approved = TV_Project.Nodes.Add("Approved Projects");
Approved_Open = Approved.Nodes.Add("Open");
Approved_Open.Nodes.Add(dr["Project ID"].ToString(), dr["Project Name"].ToString());
```

`Project ID` and `Project Name` are pulled from a database. `Project ID` returns 1 as proven in the first message box.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It will return `true` if the `tv_Projects.SelectedNode` belongs to `tv_Projects.Nodes` collection. And will return `false` if, for instance it belongs to `tv_Projects.Nodes(0).Nodes`. So to get a specific node in the TreeView control, you need to use a recursive function to iterate through the branches and get that node by the `Name` or `Tag` properties.

Comment: Thanks @JQSOFT, do you happen to have a link that describes the recursive function or alternatively, can you please explain on how to add the selected node to the tv_projects.nodes collection?

Comment: Please check [How to Iterate through all nodes of a treeView Control. C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691286/how-to-iterate-through-all-nodes-of-a-treeview-control-c-sharp) and [Get a list of all tree nodes (in all levels) in TreeView Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702051/get-a-list-of-all-tree-nodes-in-all-levels-in-treeview-controls/24856090) and many more.