# Obtaining every single free-form property and its value, converting it into a raw, readable JSON payload

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, system.text.json

Say I want to output a JSON data structure to a requester. This JSON data would:

1. **Be free-form** (Basically, it could be a value, object or even an array)
2. Be returned to the frontend directly with **no serialization** (Frontend is a JS stack, returning the JSON payload without string serialization would allow it to explicit cast on its own.)

I've been looking around StackOverflow and have found a nice snippet by @dbc:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Adapted from dbc answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60997251/3744182
    /// To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60994574/how-to-extract-all-values-for-all-jsonproperty-objects-with-a-specified-name-fro
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public static class JsonExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<JsonElement> DescendantPropertyValues(this JsonElement element)
        {
            var query = RecursiveEnumerableExtensions.Traverse(
                    (Name: (string) null, Value: element),
                    t =>
                    {
                        switch (t.Value.ValueKind)
                        {
                            case JsonValueKind.Array:
                                return t.Value.EnumerateArray().Select(i => ((string) null, i));
                            case JsonValueKind.Object:
                                return t.Value.EnumerateObject().Select(p => (p.Name, p.Value));
                            default:
                                return Enumerable.Empty<(string, JsonElement)>();
                        }
                    }, false)
                .Select(t => t.Value);
            return query;
        }
    }

    public static class RecursiveEnumerableExtensions
    {
        // Rewritten from the answer by Eric Lippert https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert
        // to "Efficient graph traversal with LINQ - eliminating recursion" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253161/efficient-graph-traversal-with-linq-eliminating-recursion
        // to ensure items are returned in the order they are encountered.
        public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(
            T root,
            Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> children, bool includeSelf = true)
        {
            if (includeSelf)
                yield return root;
            var stack = new Stack<IEnumerator<T>>();
            try
            {
                stack.Push(children(root).GetEnumerator());
                while (stack.Count != 0)
                {
                    var enumerator = stack.Peek();
                    if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        stack.Pop();
                        enumerator.Dispose();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        yield return enumerator.Current;
                        stack.Push(children(enumerator.Current).GetEnumerator());
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                foreach (var enumerator in stack)
                    enumerator.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

With these methods, I was able to output any data structure to the requester easily. But the problem is that the values returned in each property simply contain `ValueKind`.

So, how do we, instead of returning ValueKind return the actual property (Be it an object, array, etc) instead?

Even easier, if there's a method that exists which emulates what `Serialize()` does but without the '' inclusions and all, that'll be perfect for the frontend because this scenario omits the requirement of frontends to `Parse()` the incoming serialized string, allowing it to 'cast' on its own.

**Current code flow:**
Data comes in, I setup an ICollection named `concatPayload` (I need it to be a collection because I need to process other datasets/datum if more comes in and sometimes it may or may not be JSON. But if it's not JSON, it'll be converted systemically.)

```
var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(args.Data);
    concatPayload.Add(jsonDoc.RootElement.DescendantPropertyValues()
        .Where(v => v.ValueKind.IsPrimitive())
            .Select(v => v.Clone()).ToList());
```

I execute the code above recommended by dbc.

```
return Ok(await _api.Dispatch(vm)); // The Dispatch method runs the concatPayload population flow.
```

Simply put,

1. I take in a source,
2. I process it, validate if its a JSON or not. If it is, I'll do the above-mentioned parsing to validate. If not, I'll convert it over to JSON.
3. I stash it as an ICollection
4. I return the entire ViewModel

   public class DispatchViewModel
   {
   /// 
   /// If this pops up, user must have done something bad
   /// 
   public string? ErrorReason { get; set; }

   ```
       /// <summary>
       /// The raw payload of the object, in JSON.
       /// </summary>
       public ICollection<object> Payload { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Comment: Are you just trying to re-serialize the value of a `JsonElement`?  If so you can use `JsonSerializer` to do it, see e.g. https://dotnetfiddle.net/wjphKy.  Don't forget to clone them if they need to persist past the lifetime of the `JsonDocument`.

Comment: @dbc I have almost achieved what I want through: ```jsonDoc.RootElement.DescendantPropertyValues()
                                            .Where(v => v.ValueKind.IsPrimitive())
                                            .Select(v => v.Clone().GetRawText()).ToList()``` problem is, the array's structure seemed to have merged. 

I have a sample code for you to refer to in case you need to find out what payload i'm processing.

https://github.com/nozomi-ai/websocket-sharp/blob/feature/sync-fix/WebSocketSharp.NetCore.Tests/WebSocketClientTests.cs

Refer to AsyncClientTestListeners

Comment: https://pastebin.com/HVyr2zyA

Sample here @dbc

Instead of getting ```[{"e":"24hrTicker","E":1597024964584,"s":"ETHBTC","p":"-0.00062900"...```

I'm getting ```[ "[{\"e\":\"24hrTicker\",\"E\":1597024913563,\"s\":\"ETHBTC\",\"p\":\"-0.00056100\",``` As if something is helping me before it gets sent to frontend..

Comment: Well that sounds like you are double-serializing.  I.e. you are returning a JSON string from your API, which then gets serialized a second time.  You can just return an `IEnumerable<JsonElement>` and it will get serialized once, properly, without needing to serialize it yourself.

Comment: @dbc I've updated my content on the post for more granularity. Anyway, the .GetRawText() approach I did (On top of your methods) was the closest I got. It gave me what I needed but it destroyed the Array and Object structures.