# How to recursively descend a System.Text.Json JsonNode hierarchy (equivalent to Json.NET's JToken.DescendantsAndSelf())?

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I have an arbitrary JSON document (i.e. without a fixed schema that is known in advance) and I would like to recursively descend it to search for all nodes at any level in the document that match some predicate, so that I can make some necessary modifications.  How can I perform such a recursive search using the [`JsonNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode?view=net-6.0) document object model?

Specifics are as follows.

Say I have some JSON such as the following that may contain one or more instances of a property `"password"` inside:

```json
[
  {
    "column1": "val_column1",
    "column2": "val_column2",
    "sheet2": [
      {
        "sheet2col1": "val_sheet2column1",
        "sheet3": [
          {
            "sheet3col1": "val_sheet3column1",
            "password": "password to remove"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "sheet2col1": "val_sheet2column1",
        "sheet3": [
          {
            "sheet3col1": "val_sheet3column1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "column1": "val2_column1",
    "column2": "val2_column2",
    "password": "password to remove",
    "sheet2": [
      {
        "sheet2col1": "val_sheet2column1",
        "sheet3": [
          {
            "sheet3col2": "val_sheet3column2"
          },
          null,
          null,
          19191
        ],
        "password": "password to remove"
      },
      {
        "sheet2col1": "val_sheet2column1",
        "sheet3": [
          {
            "sheet3col2": "val_sheet3column2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to parse it to a `JsonNode` hierarchy and remove all of the "password" properties wherever they may appear in the JSON hierarchy.  With Json.NET, I could parse to `JToken` and use [`DescendantsAndSelf()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_DescendantsAndSelf.htm):

```
var root = JToken.Parse(json);
var propertyToRemove = "password";
if (root is JContainer c)
    foreach (var obj in c.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JObject>().Where(o => o.ContainsKey(propertyToRemove)))
        obj.Remove(propertyToRemove);
var newJson = root.ToString();
```

But `JsonNode` does not have an equivalent method.  How can I do this using System.Text.Json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `JsonNode` does not have an equivalent to [`DescendantsAndSelf()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_DescendantsAndSelf.htm) we will have to create one ourselves:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<JsonNode?> Descendants(this JsonNode? root) => root.DescendantsAndSelf(false);

    /// Recursively enumerates all JsonNodes in the given JsonNode object in document order.
    public static IEnumerable<JsonNode?> DescendantsAndSelf(this JsonNode? root, bool includeSelf = true) => 
        root.DescendantItemsAndSelf(includeSelf).Select(i => i.node);
    
    /// Recursively enumerates all JsonNodes (including their index or name and parent) in the given JsonNode object in document order.
    public static IEnumerable<(JsonNode? node, int? index, string? name, JsonNode? parent)> DescendantItemsAndSelf(this JsonNode? root, bool includeSelf = true) => 
        RecursiveEnumerableExtensions.Traverse(
            (node: root, index: (int?)null, name: (string?)null, parent: (JsonNode?)null),
            (i) => i.node switch
            {
                JsonObject o => o.AsDictionary().Select(p => (p.Value, (int?)null, p.Key.AsNullableReference(), i.node.AsNullableReference())),
                JsonArray a => a.Select((item, index) => (item, index.AsNullableValue(), (string?)null, i.node.AsNullableReference())),
                _ => i.ToEmptyEnumerable(),
            }, includeSelf);
    
    static IEnumerable<T> ToEmptyEnumerable<T>(this T item) => Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    static T? AsNullableReference<T>(this T item) where T : class => item;
    static Nullable<T> AsNullableValue<T>(this T item) where T : struct => item;
    static IDictionary<string, JsonNode?> AsDictionary(this JsonObject o) => o;
}

public static partial class RecursiveEnumerableExtensions
{
    // Rewritten from the answer by Eric Lippert https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert
    // to "Efficient graph traversal with LINQ - eliminating recursion" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253161/efficient-graph-traversal-with-linq-eliminating-recursion
    // to ensure items are returned in the order they are encountered.
    public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(
        T root,
        Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> children, bool includeSelf = true)
    {
        if (includeSelf)
            yield return root;
        var stack = new Stack<IEnumerator<T>>();
        try
        {
            stack.Push(children(root).GetEnumerator());
            while (stack.Count != 0)
            {
                var enumerator = stack.Peek();
                if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    stack.Pop();
                    enumerator.Dispose();
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return enumerator.Current;
                    stack.Push(children(enumerator.Current).GetEnumerator());
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            foreach (var enumerator in stack)
                enumerator.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

And now we will be able to do:

```
var root = JsonNode.Parse(json);

var propertyToRemove = "password";
foreach (var obj in root.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JsonObject>().Where(o => o.ContainsKey(propertyToRemove)))
    obj.Remove(propertyToRemove);

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true /* Use whatever you want here */ };
var newJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(root, options);
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cfH7wY).

Keep in mind the following differences with Json.NET's [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm):

1. The `JsonNode` returned for a `null` JSON value (e.g. `{"value":null}`) will **actually be null**.  LINQ to JSON represents a `null` JSON value as a non-null [`JValue`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue.htm) with `JValue.Type` equal to `JTokenType.Null`.
2. `JsonNode` does not have any equivalent to Json.NET's [`JProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jproperty.htm).  The [parent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode.parent?view=net-6.0) of a value in an object will be the object itself.  Thus there's no straightforward way to determine the property name of a selected `JsonNode` property value via the `JsonNode` document object model.

Thus if you need to search for and modify properties by value (rather than by name), you can use the second extension method `DescendantItemsAndSelf()` which includes the parent and name or index along with the current node.  E.g., to remove all `null` property values, do the following:

```
foreach (var item in root.DescendantItemsAndSelf().Where(i => i.name != null && i.node == null).ToList())
    ((JsonObject)item.parent!).Remove(item.name!);
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fXl1QH).

Answer (score 2):

Building on top of the comprehensive [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73887518/6682) by [@dbc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc), you can avoid much of the auxiliary code and extensions by leveraging [`TraverseDepthFirst`](https://morelinq.github.io/3.4/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_TraverseDepthFirst__1.htm) (or [`TraverseBreadthFirst`](https://morelinq.github.io/3.4/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_TraverseBreadthFirst__1.htm)) from [MoreLINQ](https://morelinq.github.io/).

Here's a simple example of how:

```
using MoreLinq;

var node = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonNode>("""
               { "array": [true, false, null, 42, {}] }
               """);

var result = MoreEnumerable.TraverseDepthFirst((object?)node, node => node switch
{
    JsonObject obj => from m in obj
                      from mn in new object?[] { m, m.Value }
                      select mn,
    JsonArray arr  => from object? e in arr.Index() // Index from MoreLINQ
                      select e,
    _              => Enumerable.Empty<object?>(),
});
```

`result` will be a sequence of one of the following:

- `null`
- `JsonArray`
- `JsonObject`
- `JsonValue` for a JSON scalar (Boolean, number, `true` or `false`)
- `KeyValuePair<string, JsonNode?>` for an object member/property where key is the name
- `KeyValuePair<int, JsonNode?>` for an array element where key is index

Unfortunately, there are three problems:

1. `result` will be of type `IEnumerable<object?>` since `object` is the only common ancestor of the above listed types.
2. The cast to `object` will cause the key-value pairs (`KeyValuePair<string, JsonNode?>` and `KeyValuePair<int, JsonNode?>`) to be boxed.
3. You lose the connection to the parent of the object members and array elements.

These problems can be solved by introducing a light-weight structure as a union that covers all cases:

```
readonly record struct JsonTreeNode
{
    readonly int index; // 0 = undefined

    JsonTreeNode(int index, string? name, JsonNode? node, JsonNode? parent) => (this. Index, Name, Node, Parent) = (index, name, node, parent);
    public JsonTreeNode(JsonNode? node, JsonNode? parent) : this(0, null, node, parent) { }
    public JsonTreeNode(string name, JsonNode? node, JsonObject parent) : this(0, name, node, parent) { }
    public JsonTreeNode(int index, JsonNode? node, JsonArray parent) : this(index + 1, null, node, parent) { }

    public int Index => this. Index - 1;
    public string? Name { get; }
    public JsonNode? Node { get; }
    public JsonNode? Parent { get; }

    public bool IsObjectMember => Name is not null;
    public bool IsArrayElement => Index >= 0;

    public KeyValuePair<string, JsonNode?> AsObjectMember() =>
        Name is { } name
        ? KeyValuePair.Create(name, Node)
        : throw new InvalidOperationException("Node is not a JSON object member");

    public KeyValuePair<int, JsonNode?> AsArrayElement() =>
        IsArrayElement
        ? KeyValuePair.Create(Index, Node)
        : throw new InvalidOperationException("Node is not a JSON array element.");
}
```

With this, you can use `TraverseDepthFirst` as follows:

```
var result = MoreEnumerable.TraverseDepthFirst(new JsonTreeNode(node, null), (node => node switch
{
    { Node: JsonObject obj } => obj.Select(p => new JsonTreeNode(p.Key, p.Value, obj)),
    { Node: JsonArray arr  } => arr.Select((e, i) => new JsonTreeNode(i, e, arr)),
    _                        => Enumerable.Empty<JsonTreeNode>(),
}));
```

`result` will be typed as `IEnumerable<JsonTreeNode>`, the parents will be linked and there won't be any boxing.

See also [demo on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/R1ttOi).

Comment: `public int Index => this. Index - 1` -- should that be **`this.index- 1`**?  As it is it looks to throw a stack overflow exception.

Comment: @dbc Absolutely and strange how that slipped in because when I checked my [test source](http://share.linqpad.net/vcvvv8.linq), it wasn't there. Anyway, fixed the example and thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

First define the following extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<JsonNode> Descendants(this JsonNode node)
    {
        if (node is JsonObject jObj)
        {
            foreach (var pty in jObj)
            {
                yield return pty.Value;
                foreach (var child in pty.Value.Descendants())
                    yield return child;
            }
        }
        else if (node is JsonArray jArray)
        {
            foreach (var elt in jArray)
            {
                yield return elt;
                foreach (var child in elt.Descendants())
                    yield return child;
            }
        }
        else
            yield break;
    }
```

You can use it as follows:

```
        var doc = JsonNode.Parse(raw);

        var descendants = doc.Descendants().ToArray();

        foreach (var o in descendants.OfType<JsonObject>().Where(o => o.ContainsKey("password")))
        {
            o.Remove("password");
        }
```