# Deserialize `false` as `null` with System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I’m accessing an api that for some reason returns `false` whenever `null` would be used normally.

I now need a way to deserialize an arbitrary json string into a completely generic type and interpreting `JsonTokenType.False` as `JsonTokenType.Null` for any Nullable / reference type property no matter how deep it’s nested.

(I’m targeting `net7.0` and `netstandard2.0` and use `System.Text.Json`)

---

### Example data (Needs to work for ANY schema!)

```json
{
   "property": false // expected type: string
   "property2": false // expected type: int
   "property3": { // data might be nested
      "property": false // expected type SomeType
   }
}
```

```cs
public sealed class JsonDefinition {
   public string? Property { get; set; }
   public int? Property2 { get; set; }
   public NestedJsonType? Property { get; set; }
}
public sealed class NestedJsonType{
   public SomeType? Property { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You have to post your json, how else we can help  you?

Comment: That’s the point; The schema might be completely arbitrary!
In fact it have do deserialize many different schemas for different database tables.
I need a completely generic solution, that can handle `false` as `null`…

Comment: Call the owner of the JSON api. They should stick to standards and change their behaviour. Or they can tell you how other customers solved this issue.

Comment: You post just json, it is not enough, pls post the class you are trying to deserialize it. And pls select more real example. We need something to test if you really want to get a solution.

Comment: But I think Text.Json is a wrong serializer for this kind of work. It would be much more easier to use Newtonsof.Json

Comment: 1) Do you need to apply your converter to collection items, or just to property values? 2) Can you use .NET 7?

Comment: It should only be needed on objects (no collections).
I am targeting `net7.0` but I need a fallback solution for `netstandard2.0` as I'm using this inside a UWP app as well

Comment: The [System.Text.Json nuget 7.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json) supports netstandard2.0, can you use that?

Comment: Sure, I haven't thought about using the nuget package!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you are using .NET 7** (or the [System.Text.Json nuget version 7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json/)) or later, you can add a [`DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts#modifiers) that applies a "false as default" converter to every property of every type encountered during deserialization:

First, create the following `Action<JsonTypeInfo>` modifier:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static Action<JsonTypeInfo> AddFalseToDefaultPropertyConverter { get; } = 
        static typeInfo => 
        {
            if (typeInfo.Kind != JsonTypeInfoKind.Object)
                return;
            foreach (var property in typeInfo.Properties)
            {
                // TODO: Modify these checks as required.
                // For instance if PropertyType is declared as typeof(object) or typeof(JsonNode) or typeof(JsonElement?) you may want to let `false` be deserialized as-is.
                if ((!property.PropertyType.IsValueType || Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) != null) && property.CustomConverter == null)
                    property.CustomConverter = (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(FalseAsDefaultConverter<>).MakeGenericType(property.PropertyType))!;
            }
        };
    
    class FalseAsDefaultConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T>
    {
        public override T? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            reader.TokenType switch
            {
                JsonTokenType.False => default,
                _ =>JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(ref reader, options),
            };
        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => 
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, options);
    }
}
```

And now you will be able to deserialize your JSON as follows:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
    {
        Modifiers = { JsonExtensions.AddFalseToDefaultPropertyConverter },
    },
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    ReadCommentHandling = JsonCommentHandling.Skip,
    // Add other options as required:
    WriteIndented = true,
};

var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonDefinition>(input, options);
```

Notes:

- Because the converter is applied directly to each serialized property, there is no problem with recursion.
- This solution does not handle `false` values for the **root object**, or for **collection items**.
- You may need to tweak the `// TODO: Modify these checks as required.` logic that selects the property types to which to apply the converter.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QHxx89).

**If you are using .NET 6** then contract customization is not available. Instead, you could preload into a [`JsonNode`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode?view=net-6.0) hierarchy and recursively remove all `false` property values:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonNode? RemoveFalseProperties(this JsonNode? root)
    {
        foreach (var item in root.DescendantItemsAndSelf(false).Where(i => i.name != null && i.node is JsonValue v && v.TryGetValue<bool>(out var b) && b == false).ToList())
            ((JsonObject)item.parent!).Remove(item.name!);
        return root;
    }
    
    //Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73887517/how-to-recursively-descend-a-system-text-json-jsonnode-hierarchy-equivalent-to
    /// Recursively enumerates all JsonNodes (including their index or name and parent) in the given JsonNode object in document order.
    public static IEnumerable<(JsonNode? node, int? index, string? name, JsonNode? parent)> DescendantItemsAndSelf(this JsonNode? root, bool includeSelf = true) => 
        RecursiveEnumerableExtensions.Traverse(
            (node: root, index: (int?)null, name: (string?)null, parent: (JsonNode?)null),
            (i) => i.node switch
            {
                JsonObject o => o.AsDictionary().Select(p => (p.Value, (int?)null, p.Key.AsNullableReference(), i.node.AsNullableReference())),
                JsonArray a => a.Select((item, index) => (item, index.AsNullableValue(), (string?)null, i.node.AsNullableReference())),
                _ => i.ToEmptyEnumerable(),
            }, includeSelf);

    static IEnumerable<T> ToEmptyEnumerable<T>(this T item) => Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    static T? AsNullableReference<T>(this T item) where T : class => item;
    static Nullable<T> AsNullableValue<T>(this T item) where T : struct => item;
    static IDictionary<string, JsonNode?> AsDictionary(this JsonObject o) => o;
}

public static partial class RecursiveEnumerableExtensions
{
    // Rewritten from the answer by Eric Lippert https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert
    // to "Efficient graph traversal with LINQ - eliminating recursion" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253161/efficient-graph-traversal-with-linq-eliminating-recursion
    // to ensure items are returned in the order they are encountered.
    public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(
        T root,
        Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> children, bool includeSelf = true)
    {
        if (includeSelf)
            yield return root;
        var stack = new Stack<IEnumerator<T>>();
        try
        {
            stack.Push(children(root).GetEnumerator());
            while (stack.Count != 0)
            {
                var enumerator = stack.Peek();
                if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    stack.Pop();
                    enumerator.Dispose();
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return enumerator.Current;
                    stack.Push(children(enumerator.Current).GetEnumerator());
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            foreach (var enumerator in stack)
                enumerator.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

And then, to deserialize, do:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    ReadCommentHandling = JsonCommentHandling.Skip,
    // Add other options as required:
    WriteIndented = true,
};

var model = JsonNode.Parse(input, documentOptions : new() { CommentHandling = JsonCommentHandling.Skip })
    .RemoveFalseProperties()
    .Deserialize<JsonDefinition>(options);
```

Notes:

- This solution is more robust than a simple string replacement such as `input.Replace("false", "null")` since it is quite possible that the text `false` may appear within some JSON string.
- System.Text.Json.Nodes lacks an equivalent to [`JContainer.Descendants()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Descendants.htm) so we have to write one ourselves.

Demo #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0I2uH2).

I removed `false` properties because it seemed more robust than replacing them with `null`.  If you would prefer to replace with `null` you will need to add in a `JsonConverter<bool>` that maps `null` to `false` for `bool` values.

```
public class BoolConverter : JsonConverter<bool>
{
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, bool value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        writer.WriteBooleanValue(value);
    
    public override bool Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        reader.TokenType switch
        {
            JsonTokenType.True => true,
            JsonTokenType.False => false,
            JsonTokenType.Null => false,
            _ => throw new JsonException(),
        };
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonNode? ReplaceFalseWithNullProperties(this JsonNode? root)
    {
        foreach (var item in root.DescendantItemsAndSelf(false).Where(i => i.name != null && i.node is JsonValue v && v.TryGetValue<bool>(out var b) && b == false).ToList())
            ((JsonObject)item.parent!)[item.name!] = null;
        return root;
    }
}
```

And then deserialize like so:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    ReadCommentHandling = JsonCommentHandling.Skip,
    Converters = { new BoolConverter() },
    // Add other options as required:
    WriteIndented = true,
};

var model = JsonNode.Parse(input, documentOptions : new() { CommentHandling = JsonCommentHandling.Skip })
    .ReplaceFalseWithNullProperties()
    .Deserialize<JsonDefinition>(options);
```

Demo #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mwYPV4).

Comment: Thank you very much @dbc! That's a very nice and robust solution and above all exactly what I thought of!
I adopted your code snippets to a solution that seems to works great for my need!
https://gist.github.com/ShortDevelopment/62585ee538eed00e667df3870616579d

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'll just go with sth like `input.Replace("false", "null")` for now...

Answer (score 0):

System.Text.Json is only good for a demo to serialize "Hello World". I tried to use it , but code is getting unnecessary complicated. So I give you a Newtonsoft.Json converter. If you are a fan of Text.Json try to convert to it and you will see what I am talking about

```
JsonDefinition data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonDefinition>(json, new FalseJsonConverter<JsonDefinition>());

public class FalseJsonConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T> 
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, T? value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override T? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, T? existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject o = JObject.Load(reader);

        var falses = o.DescendantsAndSelf()
                    .Where(x => (x.Type == JTokenType.Boolean))
                    .Select(x => (JProperty)x.Parent)
                    .ToList();

        for (var i = 0; i < falses.Count(); i++)
            if ((Boolean)falses[i].Value == false) falses[i].Value = null;

        return o.ToObject<T>();
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```