Link one part of a JSON document to another
Can references be resolved when parsing using JsonNode.Parse in System.Text.Json.Nodes?
For example, I would like to turn this (or similar):
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "age": 21,
  "familyTree": 
  {
    "$ref": "#/parents" 
  },
  "parents": {
      "father": "Bruce Doe",
      "mother": "Mary Doe" 
  }
}

Into a JsonNode structure like this:
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "age": 21,
  "familyTree": 
  {
    "father": "Bruce Doe",
    "mother": "Mary Doe" 
  },
  "parents": {
      "father": "Bruce Doe",
      "mother": "Mary Doe" 
  }
}

But I cannot find any options in JsonNode.Parse that would allow this.  It seems this needs to be done externally.  If so, is there a way to do this with System.Text.Json, System.Text.Json.Nodes, and Json.Path?

JSON is just data structure. If your tool has this feature - use it. E.g. OpenApi has $ref key that points to other part of JSON document, but it's read by OpenApi JSON parser, so other tool would not see it as reference. See this documentation page as example: https://json-spec.readthedocs.io/reference.html

Does this answer your question? Are references possible in JSON?

No.  Question was wrong.  I've made it specific to the technologies I'm using.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

"#/parents" looks like JSON Pointer syntax not JSONPath.  There is no support for this in System.Text.Json.  You might check to see whether JsonPointer.Net can be used to resolve your "ref" value after parsing.

The value "#/parents" uses JSON Pointer syntax not JSONPath:

JSON Pointer defines a string syntax for identifying a specific value within a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) document.

There is no support for this in System.Text.Json.  Its reference tracking mechanism does not use JSON Pointer syntax for its "$ref" values.
As a workaround, you could either write your own JSON Pointer parser and evaluator, or use a third party library to parse and evaluate it.  For instance, using JsonPointer.Net by Greg Dennis (currently licensed using the MIT license), you could introduce the following extension methods:
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;
using Json.Pointer;

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonNode? ResolveJsonPointerInternalReferences(this JsonNode? root, string refName  = "$ref")
    {
        if (root == null)
            return null;
        foreach (var obj in root.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JsonObject>())
        {
            if (obj.TryGetPropertyValue(refName, out var valueNode) && valueNode is JsonValue value 
                && value.TryGetValue<string>(out var s) && s != null
                && JsonPointer.TryParse(s, out var pointer) 
                && pointer.TryEvaluate(root, out var result))
            {
                if (value.ParentsAndSelf().Contains(result))
                    throw new JsonException("Recursive back references are not supported");
                else if (!(result is JsonObject resultObj))
                    throw new JsonException("Result is not an object");
                else
                {
                    foreach (var pair in resultObj)
                        obj[pair.Key] = pair.Value?.DeepClone();
                    obj.Remove(refName);
                }
            }
        }
        return root;
    }
    
    public static IEnumerable<JsonNode> ParentsAndSelf(this JsonNode? node)
    {
        while (node != null)
        {
            yield return node;
            node = node.Parent;
        }
    }
    
    // From this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73887518/3744182
    // To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73887517/how-to-recursively-descend-a-system-text-json-jsonnode-hierarchy-equivalent-to
    public static IEnumerable<JsonNode?> Descendants(this JsonNode? root) => root.DescendantsAndSelf(false);

    /// Recursively enumerates all JsonNodes in the given JsonNode object in document order.
    public static IEnumerable<JsonNode?> DescendantsAndSelf(this JsonNode? root, bool includeSelf = true) => 
        root.DescendantItemsAndSelf(includeSelf).Select(i => i.node);
    
    /// Recursively enumerates all JsonNodes (including their index or name and parent) in the given JsonNode object in document order.
    public static IEnumerable<(JsonNode? node, int? index, string? name, JsonNode? parent)> DescendantItemsAndSelf(this JsonNode? root, bool includeSelf = true) => 
        RecursiveEnumerableExtensions.Traverse(
            (node: root, index: (int?)null, name: (string?)null, parent: (JsonNode?)null),
            (i) => i.node switch
            {
                JsonObject o => o.Select(p => (p.Value, (int?)null, p.Key.AsNullableReference(), i.node.AsNullableReference())),
                JsonArray a => a.Select((item, index) => (item, index.AsNullableValue(), (string?)null, i.node.AsNullableReference())),
                _ => i.ToEmptyEnumerable(),
            }, includeSelf);
    
    static IEnumerable<T> ToEmptyEnumerable<T>(this T item) => Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    static T? AsNullableReference<T>(this T item) where T : class => item;
    static Nullable<T> AsNullableValue<T>(this T item) where T : struct => item;
}

public static partial class RecursiveEnumerableExtensions
{
    // Rewritten from the answer by Eric Lippert https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert
    // to "Efficient graph traversal with LINQ - eliminating recursion" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253161/efficient-graph-traversal-with-linq-eliminating-recursion
    // to ensure items are returned in the order they are encountered.
    public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(
        T root,
        Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> children, bool includeSelf = true)
    {
        if (includeSelf)
            yield return root;
        var stack = new Stack<IEnumerator<T>>();
        try
        {
            stack.Push(children(root).GetEnumerator());
            while (stack.Count != 0)
            {
                var enumerator = stack.Peek();
                if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    stack.Pop();
                    enumerator.Dispose();
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return enumerator.Current;
                    stack.Push(children(enumerator.Current).GetEnumerator());
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            foreach (var enumerator in stack)
                enumerator.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

And then manually replace all "$ref" values with clones of the referenced JSON e.g. as follows:
var root = JsonNode.Parse(jsonString)
    .ResolveJsonPointerInternalReferences();

Notes:

Since the builtin "$ref" reference tracking mechanism does not use JSON Pointer syntax, be sure to confirm that the JSON you receive uses this syntax.

The extension method replaces "$ref" values with a copy of the JSON to which they refer.  As such, back references are not supported.  If you were to attempt to replace the value of a "$ref" property with a portion of the JSON document containing itself, you would get an infinite recursion.

Microsoft has a nuget package Microsoft.Json.Pointer that supports JSON Pointer -- but for Json.NET's JToken type rather than for any System.Text.Json type.
If you were willing to switch to Json.NET (which also does not support JSON Pointer out of the box) you could use Microsoft's JSON Pointer implementation.


Demo fiddle here.
