# Can every recursion be changed to iteration?

Tags: c, recursion, iteration

Is *every* recursive function convertible to iteration? What characteristic should a recursive function have in order for it to be implemented using iteration?

I've been trying to define the following function using iteration but seems like a no-go! It is supposed to explore all the paths (nodes) in a maze. Can anyone rewrite this using iterations? If it is not possible, why not?

```
typedef int[0,99] id_t;
bool visited[id_t];
int path[id_t];
int pathCounter = 0;

struct { 
    id_t id;
    bool free;
    int neighborNode[4];
} nodeMap[id_t];

void findPath(int current){
    visited[current] = true;
    for (i : int[0, 3]){
        if(nodeMap[nodeMap[current].neighborNode[i]].free == true && visited[nodeMap[current].neighborNode[i]] == false && nodeMap[current].neighborNode[i] != -1){
        path[pathCounter] = nodeMap[nodeMap[current].neighborNode[i]].id;
        pathCounter++;
        findPath(nodeMap[current].neighborNode[i]);
        path[pathCounter] = nodeMap[current].id;
        pathCounter++;      
        }
    }
    path[0] = current;
}
```

Extension: Is it possible to convert the mentioned recursive function to iteration without implementing my own stack? One of the answers suggested that every *tail recursive* function can be converted to iteration *without* using a stack structure...if that's so, is every recursive function convertible to tail recursion? How?

Comment: See also Wikipedia on [Recursion vs Iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29#Recursion_versus_iteration).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can every recursion be converted into iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931762/can-every-recursion-be-converted-into-iteration)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, every recursive function can be converted to an iterative one by following a rather mechanical process.

Recall that compilers implement recursion by using a stack, which is typically implemented in the CPU's hardware. You can build a software stack of your own, make it suitable for keeping the state of your function (i.e. its local variables), push the initial state onto that stack,  and write a `while` loop that pushes new state onto the stack instead of making a recursive call, popping the stack instead of returning, and continuing the process while the stack is not empty.

Comment: I kinda prefer not to implement my own stack, is it still possible to convert my function to an iteration?

Comment: @SabaAhang It is possible to rewrite recursion without a stack if it is a *tail call* (modern compilers do this as an optimization). In case of your specific issue, the stack is simply an array of `int`s and a scalar `int` representing the "stack pointer", so implementing your stack is very easy.

Comment: There are actually 2 numbers that need to be stored: current and i.

Answer (score 5):

It is generally possible to convert any recursive algorithm into loop. The method is simple: we can imitate how the compiler generate code for function call: entering function, returning from function, and continue execution.

To turn a recursive function into an iterative loop, you can:

- Define a record, which stores the arguments to the function and the local variables. This is equivalent to stack frame.
- Define a stack, to which records a pushed. This is analogy to the program stack.
- When a function is called, create a record of the current value of the arguments and local variables and push to stack.
- When you return from the function, pop out from stack and overwrite the current value with that from the record.

The whole process above is done in a while loop, which will exit when the stack is empty,

Answer (score 3):

Like the other answers already stated, it's technically possible to do that with simulating the stack. But I guess you don't want to do that. You probably want an iterative solution without using a stack. If that's the case you need to have a tail recursive function. AFAIR that's the only possible way. You can rewrite every tail recursive function to an imperative one without simulating a stack.

Comment: Exactly! Can you tell me more about how to convert my function to a tail recursion so later I can rewrite it using iteration? Is it possible to convert any recursion to tail recursion?

Comment: You can't convert every recursive function to a tail recursive function. Maybe it's possible with your function, I'm not sure yet ;)

Comment: The function is tree recursive, so I think that pretty much rules out being able to transform it to use tail recursion without using an auxiliary data structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a simple "tail" recursion, then you can use a loop instead (e.g. factorial function). In more complex functions, you have to use a `stack` structure and a `while (!stack.empty())` loop. However, if you have quite complex recursion, such as `Towers of Hanoi`, `Merge Sort`, and `printing truth table`, you will have to use a `stack` with `while` loop, as previous, but with a `switch` statement to determine the current status of call.

**Recursive:**

```
void mergeSort(int start, int end)
{
    if (start < end)
    {
         mergeSort(start, (start + end) / 2);
         mergeSort((start + end) / 2 + 1, end);
         Merge(start, end);
    }

}
```

**Iterative:**

```
void mergeSort()
{
  stack<int> st;
  st.push(1);
  int status;

  while (!st.empty())
  {
      status = st.pop();
      switch (status)
      {
        case 1:
             ....
            break;
        case 2:
             break;
      }
  }
}
```

I highly recommend [this excellent pdf](http://www.cs.sun.ac.za/rw711/2012term2/lectures/lec9_2010/l9_2010.pdf) which explains the process in detail.

Comment: How about the function in question? Is it a case of tail recursion? if not is it convertible to a tail recursion? How?

Comment: @SabaAhang It is not quite complex neither tail. It can be implemented using a stack. The `pdf` I provided is very good. You can learn from it how to implement it using stack

Answer (score -3):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29#Recursion_versus_iteration all recursively defined functions can be converted to iterative ones.

Comment: This is a bit too short to be an answer. Maybe if you expanded it with some more commentary.