# Recursive vs non-recursive sorting algorithms

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion

Can someone explain in English how non-recursive and recursive implementations of sorting algorithms differs from each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive sorting algorithms work by splitting the input into two or more smaller inputs and then sorting those, then combining the results. [Merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) and [quick sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) are examples of recursive sorting algorithms.

A non-recursive technique is anything that doesn't use recursion. [Insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) is a simple example of a non-recursive sorting algorithm.

Comment: This is mostly true, so I won't downvote it, but any recursive algorithm, sorting or not, can be made into a non-recursive (aka iterative) algorithm.

Comment: Insertion Sort can be implemented recursively as well. Here is one example: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-insertion-sort/

Answer (score 6):

How they differ, in what sense? Bear in mind: any recursive algorithm can be implemented as an iterative algorithm, and vice versa (take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931762/can-every-recursion-be-converted-into-iteration)). Iteration or recursion - it's just an implementation detail; although it can have a major impact in performance depending on the choice, the algorithm will be the same nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive sorting algorithm calls on itself to sort a smaller part of the array, then combining the partially sorted results. Quick-sort is an example.

A non-recursive algorithm does the sorting all at once, without calling itself. Bubble-sort is an example of a non-recursive algorithm.