# Is it possible to turn a list into a nested dict of keys *without* recursion?

Tags: python, list, recursion, dictionary, iteration

Supposing I had a list as follows:

```
mylist = ['a','b','c','d']
```

Is it possible to create, from this list, the following dict **without** using recursion/a recursive function?

```
{
  'a': {
    'b': {
      'c': {
        'd': { }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, recursion === iteration, so yes.  Do you have any code to show what you've tried?  Perhaps an answer can build off of that.

Comment: you can use simply `map`, `reduce`

Comment: @Makoto there's no specific use case I have in mind. I was simply reviewing a number of FOSS projects and noticed that most, if not all, used recursion (not incorrectly). It just got me thinking as to whether there was an alternative to recursion. Óscar López's answer is rather insightful (specifically the link), too.

Answer (score 11):

For the simple case, simply iterate and build, either from the end or the start:

```
result = {}
for name in reversed(mylist):
    result = {name: result}
```

or

```
result = current = {}
for name in mylist:
    current[name] = {}
    current = current[name]
```

The first solution can also be expressed as a one-liner using [`reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
reduce(lambda res, name: {name: res}, reversed(mylist), {})
```

Comment: Yes, this is superior to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

For this simple case at least, yes:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
cursor = built_dict = {}
for value in my_list:
    cursor[value] = {}
    cursor = cursor[value]
```

Answer (score 3):

Or for fancyness and reduced readability:

```
dict = reduce(lambda x, y: {y: x}, reversed(myList), {})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's worth mentioning that [every recursion can be converted into iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/931762/201359), although sometimes that might not be so easy. For the particular example in the question, it *is* simple enough, it's just a matter of accumulating the expected result in a variable and traversing the input list in the appropriate order. This is what I mean:

```
def convert(lst):
    acc = {}
    for e in reversed(lst):
        acc = {e: acc}
    return acc
```

Or even shorter, the above algorithm can be expressed as a one-liner (assuming Python 2.x, in Python 3.x [`reduce`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) was moved to the [`functools`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functools.html) module). Notice how the variable names in the previous solution correspond to the lambda's parameters, and how in both cases the initial value of the accumulator is `{}`:

```
def convert(lst):
    return reduce(lambda acc, e: {e: acc}, reversed(lst), {})
```

Either way, the function `convert` works as expected:

```
mylist = ['a','b','c','d']
convert(mylist)

=> {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': {}}}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link - very insightful!

Answer (score 0):

```
mydict = dict()
currentDict = mydict
for el in mylist:
  currentDict[el] = dict()
  currentDict = currentDict[el]
```