# Can any method that uses a loop be written recursively?

Tags: recursion

I know that any recursive method can be written in a way that uses loops (instead of recursion), but can any given iterative method be written recursively?

Comment: do you have any code that we can take a look at?

Comment: @Vinit no, this is more of a general question that I just couldn't find a definitive answer to anywhere else. I'm wondering because my cs teacher brought it up in class

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can every recursion be converted into iteration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931762/can-every-recursion-be-converted-into-iteration)

Comment: Actually, that question is the opposite of this. But the accepted answer mentions a theorem that states that both conversions are possible, so the answer is relevant.

Comment: I have to note something, you said that every recursive function can be written non-recursive way - that's true only for 95% of the cases, but not for all of them.

Comment: @Barmar sorry I looked at that but since the question didn't definitely warrant an answer to my question I didn't search through the answers.. Thanks, though

Comment: @user1734651 is there an example of that 5% you can link me to?

Comment: for example, scan a tree

Comment: @user1734651 Tree walking can be done iteratively. You just need to use an array to keep track of where you've been. Instead of calling yourself recursively, you push a node onto the array and go back to the beginning of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it can!  This may seem a bit circular in logic, but there are languages that are 100% turing complete with only iterative structure and others that are only recursive structures.

Therefore the two must be equivalent.

Comment: that's really cool! I didn't know that (obviously). I'll mark this as an answer in....4 minutes.. when I'm allowed to