# Optimizing String combinations in Java

Tags: java

I need to obtain all combinations of a String of length k from given elements. For example, for

```
char[] elements = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
k = 4
```

the output should be: aaaa, aaab, ..., cccc. Now I have the following code which gives proper results BUT isn't fast enough. What can I improve in my code?

```
public static ArrayList<String> printAllKLength(char[] elements, int nrElements, int patternLength) {
    ArrayList<String> patternVariations = new ArrayList<String>();
    patternVariations = printAllKLengthRec(elements, "", nrElements, patternLength, patternVariations);

    return patternVariations;
}

public static ArrayList<String> printAllKLengthRec(char[] elements, String prefix, int nrElements, int patternLength, ArrayList<String> patternVariations) {

    if (patternLength == 0) {
        patternVariations.add(prefix);
        //System.out.println(prefix);
        return patternVariations;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nrElements; ++i) {
        String newPrefix = prefix + elements[i]; 
        printAllKLengthRec(elements, newPrefix, nrElements, patternLength - 1, patternVariations); 
    }
    return patternVariations;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is an algorithms question AND does NOT belong to this forum. You need to ask it in http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's not really an algorithm question. I posted it on codereview, thanks @Tom.

Comment: When you've done that, then delete this question here. It doesn't belong to stackoverflow.

Comment: @Mohammad: Algorithms questions involving actual code are just fine here.  ["As a rule of thumb, if your question depends on code, ask on Stack Overflow; if your question calls for mathematical notation, ask on Computer Science. Algorithms expressed in pseudocode straddle the border."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in).  But if you've cross-posted to Code Review, then go ahead and delete it here to not leave a duplicate around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it without recursation ... see the explanation here.

[recursion versus iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688019/recursion-versus-iteration)

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic programming approach(memorization). Something very similar:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/