# Speeding recursive system in Julia

Tags: recursion, julia

I need to speed up this recursive system. Can anyone help?

I annotated all variables and only used Float64-consistent functions. I also tried using memoization (since the system is recursive) via Memoize.jl, but I have to compute U, V and Z thousands of times in an optimization algorithm and my computer quickly runs out of memory.

```
const Tage = 60.0
const initT = 1975.0
const Ttime = 1990.0
const K = 6.0
const β = 0.95
const s = 0.5

θ0 = [
    0.0011
 -0.0045
 -0.0075
 -0.0013
  3.60   
  0.2587
 -0.0026  
 -0.0528
  0.0060
  1.3772
  0.2932
 -0.0030
  0.0021
  0.0044
 10.2593    
  0.7498
  1.1765
]./10000

function wagem(t::Float64, agem::Float64, edum::Float64, θ::Vector{Float64})
    θ[5] + θ[6]*agem + θ[7]*agem^2 + θ[8]*edum + θ[9]*edum^2
end

function wagef(t::Float64, agef::Float64, eduf::Float64, θ::Vector{Float64})
    θ[10] + θ[11]*agef + θ[12]*agef^2 + θ[13]*eduf + θ[14]*eduf^2
end

function ζ(agem::Float64, edum::Float64, agef::Float64, eduf::Float64, θ::Vector{Float64})
    θ[1]*agem*agef + θ[2]*agem*eduf + θ[3]*edum*agef + θ[4]*edum*eduf
end

function z(t::Float64, agem::Float64, edum::Float64, agef::Float64, eduf::Float64, θ::Vector{Float64})
    ζ(agem, edum, agef, eduf, θ) + wagem(t, agem, edum, θ) + wagef(t, agef, eduf, θ)
end

function dc(θ::Vector{Float64})
    ret::Float64 = 0.0
    ret = θ[15]
    return ret
end

function Z(t::Float64, agem::Float64, edum::Float64, agef::Float64, eduf::Float64, θ::Vector{Float64})
    ret::Float64 = 0.0
    if agem >= Tage || agef >= Tage # terminal age conditions
        ret = 0.0
    elseif t >= Ttime # terminal time condition
        ret = 1.5
    else
        ret = log(
        exp(z(t, agem, edum, agef, eduf, θ) + β*Z(t+1, agem+1, edum, agef+1, eduf, θ))
        + exp(-dc(θ) + β*(V(t+1, agem+1, edum, θ) + U(t+1, agef+1, eduf, θ)))
        )
    end
    return ret
end

function V(t::Float64, agem::Float64, edum::Float64, θ::Vector{Float64})
    ret::Float64 = 0.0
    if agem >= Tage
        ret = 0.0
    elseif t >= Ttime
        ret = 1.5
    else
        suma::Float64 = 0.0
        for agef in 16.0:Tage-1, eduf in 1.0:K
            suma += exp(s*z(t, agem, edum, agef, eduf, θ) + wagem(t, agem, edum, θ) + β*(s*(Z(t+1, agem+1, edum, agef+1, eduf, θ) - V(t+1, agem+1, edum, θ) - U(t+1, agef+1, eduf, θ)) + V(t+1, agem+1, edum, θ)))
        end
        ret = log(
                exp(wagem(t, agem, edum, θ) + β*(V(t+1, agem+1, edum, θ))) + suma
                )
    end
    return ret
end

function U(t::Float64, agef::Float64, eduf::Float64, θ::Vector{Float64})
    ret::Float64 = 0.0
    if agef >= Tage
        ret = 0.0
    elseif t >= Ttime
        ret = 1.5
    else
        suma::Float64 = 0.0
        for agem in 16.0:Tage-1, edum in 1.0:K
            suma += exp((1-s)*z(t, agem, edum, agef, eduf, θ) + wagef(t, agef, eduf, θ) + β*((1-s)*(Z(t+1, agem+1, edum, agef+1, eduf, θ) - V(t+1, agem+1, edum, θ) - U(t+1, agef+1, eduf, θ)) + U(t+1, agef+1, eduf, θ)))
        end
        ret = log(
        exp(wagef(t, agef, eduf, θ) + β*(U(t+1, agef+1, eduf, θ))) + suma
        )
    end
    return ret
end
```

I want to be able to compute things like U(1984.0, 17.0, 3.0, θ0) or V(1975.0, 16.0, 1.0, θ0) very quickly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it looks like an infinite, do you get the right result?

Comment: You could also take a look at `@lazy` macro in https://github.com/one-more-minute/Lazy.jl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the code is like a monster!
You already have 3 recursive functions `U(), V(), Z()` after that, `U()` calls `V()` and vise versa, then `V()` calls `Z()` that itself calls `U()` ......
<del>try rewrite it and prevent recursive calls as much as possible, this will ends to a more efficient solution. **Check This-> [recursion versus iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688019/recursion-versus-iteration)**</del>
after that you have unnecessary repetitive calls to `U()` and `V()` inside `for` loop that must be done outside.

FIRST STEP: **temp variable**

```
function U(t::Float64, agef::Float64, eduf::Float64, θ::Vector{Float64}) 
    ret::Float64 = 0.0
    if agef >= Tage
        ret = 0.0
    elseif t >= Ttime
        ret = 1.5
    else
        suma::Float64 = 0.0
        U1 = U(t+1, agef+1, eduf, θ) # nothing to do with following loop, so I take it outside
        wagef1 = wagef(t, agef, eduf, θ) # same as above comment
        for agem in 16.0:Tage-1, edum in 1.0:K
            suma += exp((1-s)*z(t, agem, edum, agef, eduf, θ) + wagef1 + β*((1-s)*(Z(t+1, agem+1, edum, agef+1, eduf, θ, ui) - V(t+1, agem+1, edum, θ) - U1) + U1))
        end
        ret = log(
                  exp(wagef1 + β*(U1)) + suma
                  )
    end

    return ret
end

julia> @time U(1984.0, 17.0, 3.0, t0) # a test with const Tage = 19.0
  0.869675 seconds (102.77 k allocations: 2.148 MB, 0.57% gc time)
3.785563216949393
```

the above edits in both `U() and V()` makes my run **28 times faster** compare to original code.

SECOND STEP: **using right types**

next thing is mall-usage of `Float64` data type, IMO only `θ,β,s` need to be of `Float64` type, and all the other variables should declare as integers.

```
julia> @time U(1984, 17, 3, t0) # a test with const Tage = 19
  0.608982 seconds (125.77 k allocations: 2.530 MB, 0.89% gc time)
3.785563216949393
```

**now its 30% faster.** compare to previous code

THIRD STEP **Memoize.jl**

```
although already some improvements have been happened for bigger problems they are not enough, but with using the right data types, in the previous step now `Memoize.jl` will be usable:  


using Memoize
const Tage = 60%Int
const initT = 1975%Int
const Ttime = 1990%Int
const K = 6%Int
const β = 0.95
const s = 0.5

t0 = [
    0.0011
 -0.0045
 -0.0075
 -0.0013
  3.60   
  0.2587
 -0.0026  
 -0.0528
  0.0060
  1.3772
  0.2932
 -0.0030
  0.0021
  0.0044
 10.2593    
  0.7498
  1.1765
]./10000

function wagem(t::Int, agem::Int, edum::Int, θ::Vector{Float64})
    θ[5] + θ[6]*agem + θ[7]*agem^2 + θ[8]*edum + θ[9]*edum^2
end

function wagef(t::Int, agef::Int, eduf::Int, θ::Vector{Float64})
    θ[10] + θ[11]*agef + θ[12]*agef^2 + θ[13]*eduf + θ[14]*eduf^2
end

function ζ(agem::Int, edum::Int, agef::Int, eduf::Int, θ::Vector{Float64})
    θ[1]*agem*agef + θ[2]*agem*eduf + θ[3]*edum*agef + θ[4]*edum*eduf
end

function z(t::Int, agem::Int, edum::Int, agef::Int, eduf::Int, θ::Vector{Float64})
    ζ(agem, edum, agef, eduf, θ) + wagem(t, agem, edum, θ) + wagef(t, agef, eduf, θ)
end

function dc(θ::Vector{Float64})
    ret::Float64 = 0.0
    ret = θ[15]
    return ret
end

function Z(t::Int, agem::Int, edum::Int, agef::Int, eduf::Int, θ::Vector{Float64})
    ret::Float64 = 0.0
    if agem >= Tage || agef >= Tage # terminal age conditions
        ret = 0.0
    elseif t >= Ttime # terminal time condition
        ret = 1.5
    else
        ret = log(
        exp(z(t, agem, edum, agef, eduf, θ) + β*Z(t+1, agem+1, edum, agef+1, eduf, θ))
        + exp(-dc(θ) + β*(V(t+1, agem+1, edum, θ) + U(t+1, agef+1, eduf, θ)))
        )
    end
    return ret
end

@memoize function V(t::Int, agem::Int, edum::Int, θ::Vector{Float64})
    ret::Float64 = 0.0
    agef::Int = 0
    eduf::Int = 0
    if agem >= Tage
        ret = 0.0
    elseif t >= Ttime
        ret = 1.5
    else
        suma::Float64 = 0.0
        V1 = V(t+1, agem+1, edum, θ)
        wagem1 = wagem(t, agem, edum, θ)
        for agef in 16:Tage-1, eduf in 1:K
            suma += exp(s*z(t, agem, edum, agef, eduf, θ) + wagem1 + β*(s*(Z(t+1, agem+1, edum, agef+1, eduf, θ) - V1 - U(t+1, agef+1, eduf, θ)) + V1))
        end
        ret = log(
                exp(wagem1 + β*(V1)) + suma
                )
    end
    return ret
end

@memoize  function U(t::Int, agef::Int, eduf::Int, θ::Vector{Float64})
    ret::Float64 = 0.0
    agem::Int = 0
    edum::Int = 0
    if agef >= Tage
        ret = 0.0
    elseif t >= Ttime
        ret = 1.5
    else
        suma::Float64 = 0.0
        U1 = U(t+1, agef+1, eduf, θ)
        wagef1 = wagef(t, agef, eduf, θ)
        for agem in 16:Tage-1, edum in 1:K
            suma += exp((1-s)*z(t, agem, edum, agef, eduf, θ) + wagef1 + β*((1-s)*(Z(t+1, agem+1, edum, agef+1, eduf, θ) - V(t+1, agem+1, edum, θ) - U1) + U1))
        end
        ret = log(
                  exp(wagef1 + β*(U1)) + suma
                  )
    end  
    return ret
end
```

now for `Tage = 60`:

```
julia> @time U(1984, 17, 3, t0) # a test with const Tage = 60
  3.789108 seconds (27.08 M allocations: 494.135 MB, 15.12% gc time)
16.99266161490023
```

also I have tested an `Int16` version:

```
julia> @time U(1984%Int16, 17%Int16, 3%Int16, t0)
  3.596871 seconds (27.05 M allocations: 413.808 MB, 11.93% gc time)
16.99266161490023
```

**it runs 5% faster with 20% less memory allocation** compare to `Int32` version

Comment: Up to this moment, I have always believed that iteration does things better than recursion, but now I have doubts, therefore in my latest edit I remove a sentence that suggests using iteration instead of this recursive approach. Could anyone write a more efficient pure iterative approach for the above problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot @reza. In a first version of it I had several variables as integers, I switched them all to Float64 because I read that Julia is faster when it does not have to convert between types, but I am not a computer person and the languages I have used in the past do not have explicit types (I'm talking Mathematica and other statistical packages). I will check this edits you did to my code. Just for the record, the system must have a solution since I have terminal conditions for t and ages. It's just a reverse recursion system.

Comment: can a problem like this be parallelized?