# Why use a recursive function rather than `while true do` in F#?

Tags: recursion, f#, functional-programming

Whilst watching a [Pluralsight course](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=accessing-data-fsharp-type-providers&author=tomas-petricek&name=accessing-data-fsharp-type-providers-m3&clip=4&mode=live) by Tomas Petricek (who I assume knows what he is talking about), I saw code like the following...

```
let echo =
  MailboxProcessor<string>.Start(fun inbox ->
    async {
      while do true
        let! msg = inbox.Receive()
    printfn "Hello %s" msg
    })
```

Ignore the fact that this was to demo agents, I'm interested in the inner function, which uses `while do true` to keep it running indefinitely.

Whilst looking around for other example of agents, I saw that many other people use code like this...

```
let counter =
  MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->
    let rec loop n =
      async { do printfn "n = %d, waiting..." n
        let! msg = inbox.Receive()
        return! loop(n+msg) }
    loop 0)
```

Code copied from [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/MailboxProcessor).

The inner function here is recursive, and is started off by calling it with a base value before the main function declaration ends.

Now I realise that in the second case recursion is a handy way of passing a private value to the inner function without having to use a mutable local value, but is there any other reason to use recursion here rather than `while do true`? Would there be any benefit in writing the first code snippet using recursion?

I find the non-recursive version much easier to read (subjective opinion of course), which seems like a good reason to use that whenever possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Talking about `MailboxProcessor` specifically, I think the choice depends on what exactly you are doing. In general, you can always use `while` loop or recursion.

Recursion makes it easier to use immutable state and I find `while` loop nicer if you have no state or if you use mutable state. Using mutable state is often quite useful, because `MailboxProcessor` protects you from concurrent accesses and you can keep the state local, so things like `Dictionary` (efficient hash table) are often useful.

In general:

- If you don't need any state, I would prefer `while`
- If you have mutable state (like `Dictionary` or `ResizeArray`), I'd go for `while`
- If you have some immutable state (like functional list or an integer), then recursion is nicer
- If your logic switches between multiple modes of operation then you can write it as two mutually recursive functions, which is not doable nicely with loops.

Comment: Thanks, those bullet points made it really clear. Thanks also for a great course there, please do some more!

Answer (score 3):

In many cases it depends on how you like to code. Like in your example.
Everything you can write recursiv you can also write with a loop, but sometime like with recursive data structures it is easier to write the in a recursive style.
At university I learned that with recursive programming you only have to look at your next step which is pretty handy!

You might be interested in this question as it explains my answer a bit further:
[recursion versus iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688019/recursion-versus-iteration?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Thanks, great reply and very interesting link. I'm going to accept Tomas's answer, as he spelt out the options a bit more, but I appreciate yours too.

Answer (score 2):

In F# `for` and `while` loop expressions lacks capabilities common in other languages:

1. `continue` - Skip the rest of the loop and restart from the top of loop expression.
2. `break` - Stop the loop prematurely.

If you want `continue` and `break` don't do what I did in the beginning a write a very complex test expression for `while` loops. Instead tail recursion is the best answer in F#:

```
let vs : int [] = ...
let rec findPositiveNumberIndex i =
  if i < vs.Length then
    if vs.[i] > 0 then 
      Some i
    else 
      findPositiveNumberIndex (i + 1)
  else
    None
match findPositiveNumberIndex 0 with
| Some i -> printfn "First positive number index: %d" i
| None   -> printfn "No positive numbers found"
```

In code like this F# applies something call tail-call optimization (TCO) which transforms the code above into a `while` loop with `break`. This means that we won't run out of stack space and the loop is efficient. TCO is a feature that C# lacks so we don't want to write code like above in C#.

Like others are saying with tail recursion you can sometimes avoid mutable state but that's not all.

With tail recursion your loop expressions can return a result which is nice.

In addition, if you like to iterate fast in F# over types like `int64` or with increment other than `1` and `-1` you have to rely on tail recursion. The reason is that F# only does efficient `for` expressions for ints and increments of `1` and `-1`.

```
for i in 0..100 do
  printfn "This is a fast loop"

for i in 0..2..100 do
  printfn "This is a slow loop"  

for i in 0L..100L do
  printfn "This is a slow loop"
```

Sometimes when you are hunting for performance a trick is to loop towards `0` (saves a CPU register). Unfortunately the way the F# generates `for` loop code this doesn't perform as well one would hope:

```
for i = 100 downto 0 do
  printfn "Unfortunately this is not as efficient as it can be"
```

Tail recursion towards `0` saves the CPU register.

(Unfortunately the F# compiler don't merge the test and the loop instruction for tail-recursion so it's not so good as it could be)