# binary search tree (BST) find method in C#

Tags: c#, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

**how can I Write a code with these requirements?
this is the question:**
check if there is a node with key K in the tree T, and if so, return a reference to this node.
If the tree is empty, report that the node was not found and stop.
Otherwise, compare K with the key value of the root node X.

- If K=X, issue a link to this node and stop.
- If K>X, recursively search for the key K in the right subtree of T.
- If K<X, recursively search for the key K in the left subtree of T.

This is what i found:

```
public GenBT<T> Find(GenBT<T> k, T inf){ 

if (k == null) return null; 

else 

switch (inf.CompareTo(k.inf)){ 

case 1: return Find(k.RT, inf); 

case -1: return Find(k.LT, inf); 

case 0: return k; 

default: return null;} 

};
```

**but I also found that if I want to search or find in BST I have to use a code like this :**

```
struct node* search(int data){
   struct node *current = root;
   printf("Visiting elements: ");
    
   while(current->data != data){
    
      if(current != NULL) {
         printf("%d ",current->data);
            
         //go to left tree
         if(current->data > data){
            current = current->leftChild;
         }  //else go to right tree
         else {                
            current = current->rightChild;
         }
            
         //not found
         if(current == NULL){
            return NULL;
         }
      }         
   }
   
   return current;
}
```

These two look very different and I don't know which way is right and in general what is the right way of solving this question

Comment: What have you tried? Some people might like to give you an answer, but most people want to see you have at least tried something.

Comment: you didn´t post a **question**, but just what was assigned to **you**. So unless you don´t provide what you´ve tried and where specifically you´re stuck, you won´t get much help here.

Comment: @mikelegg I have added two types of codes I had, thanks for reminding me about it

Comment: @HimBromBeere I have added two types of codes I had, thanks for reminding me about it

Comment: The first solution is a recursive solution. The second one is an iterative solution. Both are valid, see this for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688019/recursion-versus-iteration

Comment: the most obious to me without diving deep into is that the first seems like C#, while the latter seems like C++. As to "which one is right" it´s pretty simply that one that gets its job done.

Comment: @JonasH, thank you for commenting and sharing that useful link. how can I use the second code to solve this question for finding "k", like what should I replace in that code. what I think is that I should replace `int data` with ` k `  and maybe `root` with `x` I don't know to be honest  .

Comment: I assume this is schoolwork, so I'm hesitant to just provide a complete solution. Your iterative example is C code, so may be a bit more difficult to read. Consider the recursive method, to make it iterative you will need to insert a loop. When you come to the recursive `Find` call, see if you can remove the call and instead modify the variables to have the same effect as the function call. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration

Comment: @JonasH yes its is one part of my university project which I'm stuck at )) thank you so much for all this information, it was all very useful

Comment: @JonasH the first code that I posted was my friend's code but after searching around and looking at other codes that one looked different from what I saw on youtube and other websites, that's the first reason I posted it here but I'm trying to do it with the second option which you said it is called iterative solution .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To transform the recursive solution to an iterative one we need to insert a loop. In the recursive case we change the node parameter for each recursion. To do the same in the iterative case we simply create a variable that is updated instead of doing a recursion.

Changed naming to make a clearer and compilable example. Note also that CompareTo can return any number, not just 0, 1, -1. So a switch is insufficient:

```
    public class Node<T>
    {
        public Node<T> Left { get; }
        public Node<T> Right { get; }
        public T Value { get; }

        public Node(Node<T> left, Node<T> right, T value)
            => (Left, Right, Value) = (left, right, value);
    }

    public static Node<T> Find<T>(Node<T> root, T target) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        var current = root;
        while (current != null)
        {
            var comparison = target.CompareTo(current.Value);
            if (comparison > 0) 
                current = current.Right;
            else if (comparison < 0)
                current = current.Left;
            else
                return current;

        }
        return null;
    }
```

See also [how to transform a recursive method to an iterative one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration) in a more generic way. Note that the example uses a stack, In your case a stack is not needed, since you only process one branch of the tree.