# How to convert a variation of ackermann function to support tail call?

Tags: scala, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization, continuation-passing, ackermann

I'm currently solving a problem which is to implement a variation of ackermann function in scala with tail call optimization support so that the stack does not overflow.

The problem is, I cannot find a way to tail-call optimize it. I'm told continuation-pass-style(CPS) would help, but even though I successfully re-implemented it with CPS style I'm still lost.

The variation of ackermann function is as such:

```
ppa(p, a, b) = p(a, b)               (if a <= 0 or b <= 0)
ppa(p, a, b) = p(a, ppa(p, a-1, b))  (if p(a, b) is even and a, b > 0)
ppa(p, a, b) = p(ppa(p, a, b-1), b)  (if p(a, b) is odd and a, b > 0)
```

The code without optimization is as such:

```scala
def ppa(p: (Int, Int) => Int, a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
  def ppa_cont(a: Int, b: Int, ret: (Int, Int) => Int): Int = {
    if (a <= 0 || b <= 0) ret(a, b)
    else (a, b) match {
      case (_, _) if (p(a, b) % 2 == 0) => ret(a, ppa_cont(a-1, b, (x, y) => ret(x, y)))
      case (_, _) => ret(ppa_cont(a, b-1, (x, y) => ret(x, y)), b)
    }
  }

  ppa_cont(a, b, p)
}
```

Another trial is as such:

```scala
def ppa(p: (Int, Int) => Int, a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
  def ppa_cont(a: Int, b: Int, cont: (Int, Int) => Int): (Int, Int) => Int = {
    if (a <= 0 || b <= 0) cont
    else if (p(a, b) % 2 == 0) (a, b) => cont(a, ppa_cont(a-1, b, cont)(a-1, b))
    else (a, b) => cont(ppa_cont(a, b-1, cont)(a, b-1), b)
  }
 
  ppa_cont(a, b, p)(a, b)
}
```

I tried to tail-call optimize it as such:

```scala
def ppa(p: (Int, Int) => Int, a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def ppa_cont(a: Int, b: Int, ret: (Int, Int) => TailRec[Int]): TailRec[Int] = {
    if (a <= 0 || b <= 0) tailcall(ret(a, b))
    else (a, b) match {
      case (_, _) if (p(a, b) % 2 == 0) => {
        tailcall(ret(a, ppa_cont(a-1, b, (x, y) => ret(x-1, y))))
      }
      case (_, _) => {
        tailcall(ret(ppa_cont(a, b-1, (x, y) => ret(x, y-1)), b))
      }
    }
  }

  val lifted: (Int, Int) => TailRec[Int] = (x, y) => done(p(x, y))

  ppa_cont(a, b, lifted).result
}
```

But this won't compile because of type mismatches.

What could be the problem? Am I going in a wrong direction? Little hints and helping hands will be appreciated. Thx :)

p.s. I got the hint from: [why scala doesn't make tail call optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539488/why-scala-doesnt-make-tail-call-optimization)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33217360/can-this-implementation-of-ackermann-function-be-called-tail-recursive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `cats.free.Trampoline` or `scala.util.control.TailCalls.TailRec`. It's not `@tailrec` but stack-safe.

```
import scala.util.control.TailCalls._

def ppa(p: (Int, Int) => Int, a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
  def hlp(a: Int, b: Int): TailRec[Int] = {
    if (a <= 0 || b <= 0) done(p(a, b))
    else if (p(a, b) % 2 == 0) tailcall(hlp(a - 1, b)).map(p(a, _))
    else tailcall(hlp(a, b - 1)).map(p(_, b))
  }

  hlp(a, b).result
}
```

http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/stackless-scala-with-free-monads.html

http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/tail-recursive-monads.html

Actually your function doesn't look like Ackermann. Actual Ackermann makes two recursive calls

```
f(m, n) = f(m - 1, f(m, n - 1))
```

Your function makes single recursive call. It's not hard to write iterative version of your function (usually tail recursion is used because compiler can transform it to iterative version automatically). Suppose we already calculated `ppa(i, j)` for `0 <= i <= a - 1`, `0 <= j <= b - 1` (yellow area). Then we calculate two orange segments `(a, 0), (a, 1), ..., (a, b - 1)` (in this order) and `(0, b), (1, b), ..., (a - 1, b)` (in this order). Then we calculate red cell `(a, b)`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! From what I understood, tailcall(hlp(a - 1, b)).map(p(a, _)) basically does 'continuation' by passing whatever value tailcall(hlp(a - 1, b)) returns to p(a, _) and it seems this is somehow connected to trampolining. Could you perhaps explain more about this?

Comment: @PeaceSong Continuation is a monad and trampoline is a monad as well. Trampolines (and generally free monads) are explained at those links to "Herding Cats" tutorial. I'm not sure I would explain them better. Feel free to ask specific questions.