# Programmatically remove comments from Java File

Tags: java, regex, comments

I need to write a Java method

```
public static String removeComments(String code);
```

that removes all Java comments from a String. I know that questions like these have been asked before but:

- Using complicated regex-Expressions for multi-line comments like `text = text.replaceAll("(?:/\\*(?:[^*]|(?:\\*+[^*/]))*\\*+/)|(?://.*)", " ");` works fine in small tests, but often throws Stackoverflows in my real-world cases (the | in regex leads to branching).
- Many people posted some "simple" functions they came up with where you can easily construct counter examples (like having // in a String literal, e.g. in a URL).

So is there a reliable, non-recursive way of solving this problem?

Comment: What do you mean with "non-recursive"? Why would you care whether it is recursive, why would you exclude a whole class of solutions?

Comment: Well, the answer to your question is [Yes!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931762/can-every-recursion-be-converted-into-iteration), but the *how* is the difficult part.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Ok, I don't mean non-recursive, but just not excessively recursive like in the regex which kills my stack.

Comment: Don't use a regex for this. Iterate through character-by-character, looking for the start of comments, end of comments, start of string literals etc.

Comment: I would definitely prefer that, but crafting that yourself is difficult because I probably forget some strange special cases (and I need to process a huge amount of source-code, I cannot check that by hand afterwards).