# Walk folder tree without recursion c#

Tags: c#, recursion

How to change this recursive loop with non recursive?
I know this method is easy way but i'm interested in non recursive way of this solution.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace NonRecursion {
    class NonRecursion {
        static void Main() {
            string createPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

            string getPath = createPath + @"\folder";
            GetDirsPath(getPath);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void GetDirsPath(string getPath) {
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(getPath);

            for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine(dirs[i]);
                GetDirsPath(dirs[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can i change only this function?

```
static void GetDirsPath(string getPath) {
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(getPath);

            for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine(dirs[i]);
                GetDirsPath(dirs[i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hint: You'll want to use a Queue<> or a Stack<> in `GetDirsPath`

Comment: Is this an excercise or not? Because if this is not an excercise then you should look at the version of [GetDirectories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143314(v=vs.110).aspx) that walks for you the subfolder tree and returns everything with a single call

Comment: And you should choose queue and stack by the kind of traversal you need to do, whether it's breadth-first or depth-first.

Comment: can i make it without using stack or queue?

Comment: The theory says that any recursive method can be converted into a non-reciursive solution.

Comment: Yes but how can I convert it in non-recursive method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can every recursion be converted into iteration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931762/can-every-recursion-be-converted-into-iteration)

Comment: https://www.cmpe.boun.edu.tr/~akin/cmpe160/recursion.html

Comment: The recursive method is needed in this case.  You  are missing in your code an exception handler in case you don't have credentials to access a folder.  The exception will cause the program to halt without completing. Using a recursive methods will allow the application to continue when a credential exception occurs.

Comment: @Mr.Pro I suggest adding more details to your question and what exactly you want. Usually general and unclear questions get general answers. Non-recursive approach would need some kind of stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> AllFolders(string root)
{
    var folders = new Stack<string>();
    folders.Push(root);

    while (folders.Count > 0)
    {
        string folder = folders.Pop();
        yield return folder;

        foreach (var item in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(folder))
            folders.Push(item);
    }
}
```

Test code (console app):

```
static void Main()
{
    foreach (var dir in AllFolders("<your root folder here>"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dir);
    }
}
```

Here's an alternative approach using a `List<string>`:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> AllFolders(string root)
{
    var folders = new List<string> {root};

    while (folders.Count > 0)
    {
        string folder = folders[folders.Count - 1];
        folders.RemoveAt(folders.Count-1);
        yield return folder;
        folders.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(folder));
    }
}
```

These both work the same way:

They maintain a list (or stack) of directories that have not yet been output, starting with the root directory.

The algorithms remove the topmost (stack) or last (list) directory from the stack/list and output it. Then they add all the subdirectories of that directory to the list/stack and repeat, until the list/stack is empty.

In particular, note that the `List<>` version is in fact merely using a `List<>` as a `Stack<>`, so it's algorithmically identical.

If you just want to make minimal changes to the `GetDirsPath()` method:

```
static void GetDirsPath(string getPath)
{
    var dirs = new List<string> { getPath };

    while (dirs.Count > 0)
    {
        string dir = dirs[dirs.Count - 1];
        dirs.RemoveAt(dirs.Count - 1);
        Console.WriteLine(dir);
        dirs.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dir));
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but I only want to change GetDirPath function.

Comment: "How about this" is similar to "try this" for me. I don't like "try this" answers, because I can try a lot, just for finding out that it does not work. Your answer differs very much from OPs answer, so it seems to me that you have not converted his recursive code into non-recursive, but re-written everything.

Comment: @Mr.Pro Added a version with minimal changes to `GetDirsPath()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use GetDirectories method:

```
string getPath = createPath + @"\folder";

var allDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(getPath, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

To get iterate through them:

```
foreach (string dir in allDirectories) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(dir);
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx

Comment: I know this method but I only want to change GetDirPath function.