# Condition statement without loops

Tags: python

I'm writing a small function to check if all elements in a list are less than or equal to a limit. This is just for practice, and should be done without using any loops.

```
def small_enough(a, limit): 
    return all(x <= limit for x in a)
small_enough([66, 101], 200)
```

Been on this for a while but I can not find any substituting code to replace the `for` loop.This code works perfectly fine as it is - however, I am trying to get the results without using loops. Trying to write something a bit more 'pythonic'.

Comment: You can be more pythonic or have fewer loops, but not both.

Comment: I think your solution is as Pythonic as it gets.

Comment: So having loops is the python way?

Comment: Doing anything that examines every element of a list of arbitrary size is *by definition* a loop.

Comment: Yes, but not all loops are necessarily multi-line "for x in iterable: ..." loops. What you have is a loop, and it's fine.

Comment: @pragmaticlearner I'd say "using built-in/library functions with neat comprehensions"

Comment: In the future, if you have working code and are trying to improve it, consider going to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: No matter how you solve it, it involve a loop, either explicit or implicit (if using numpy or something similar).

Comment: Oh ok! Thanks for the quick responses everyone. @kojiro Will do!

Comment: You can go with a recursive function, but that's practically a loop too.

Comment: If you want to really hide the loop, you'd need some higher-order functions like `functools.reduce(operator.and_, map(lambda x: x <= limit, a), True)`. I'm pretty sure most people would consider that *less* Pythonic, though.

Comment: I would consider the `for` keyword in this case to be a generator, rather than a loop, and you solved for the main intent by using `all` rather than an explicit `return False` within a loop and `return True` if you complete the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general,

```
f(x) for x in xs == map(f, xs)
```

so

```
def small_enough(a, limit): 
    return all(map(lambda x: x <= limit, a))
```

Comment: Excuse my inexperience,but what does lambda do?

Comment: It's an expression that defines an anonymous function.

Comment: @pragmaticlearner Check out [the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions).

Answer (score 4):

If using `numpy` is ok, you can do

```
import numpy as np

x = np.asarray([66,101])
print(all(x <= 200))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's always a loop somewhere, even if you can't see it, and here's just one solution without a **`for`** loop:

```
def small_enough(a, limit): 
    return not sum(map(lambda x : x > limit, a))

print(small_enough([66, 101], 200))  #  True
print(small_enough([66, 201], 200))  #  False
```

Comment: Calling dundermethods directly is not a good idea. Here's just one example that doesn't work: `(3).__gt__(2.0)` -> `NotImplemented`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I just rolled-back my edit, I was using a lambda before, and thanks for your comment, it is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use recursion here:

```
def small_enough(a, limit):
    if a:
        return a[0] <= limit and small_enough(a[1:], limit)
    else:
        return True
```

or even

```
def small_enough(a, limit):
    return not a or (a[0] <= limit and small_enough(a[1:], limit))
```

But your solution is really much more readable than this. Besides, recursion [doesn't actually avoid looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931762/can-every-recursion-be-converted-into-iteration), it just looks different.

Comment: The recursion is also horrendously inefficient (and, for large enough `a`, will probably produce an exception).

Comment: @chepner that said, recursion does force you to give some thought to the construction of the code. In this case, I had to ask myself "does OP really want the answer to be `True` when the input list is empty?" I stuck with what `all` does, but I think it's nevertheless useful to have to think about stuff in more than one way.

Comment: And worth pointing out Python doesn't have tail call optimization, so rewriting loops as tail recursion is an anti-pattern in Python