# Is it safe to call a function from within the same function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, recursion

I've been reading up on sorting algorithms. I came across this code for Merge Sort:

```
def mergeSort(arr):
    if len(arr) > 1:
        mid = len(arr)//2
        L = arr[:mid]
        R = arr[mid:]
        #function calls itself here<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        mergeSort(L)# Sorting the first half
        mergeSort(R)# Sorting the second half

        i = j = k = 0
    
        # Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] 
        while i < len(L) and j < len(R):
            if L[i] < R[j]:
                arr[k] = L[i] 
                i+= 1
            else: 
                arr[k] = R[j] 
                j+= 1
                k+= 1
    
        # Checking if any element was left 
        while i < len(L): 
            arr[k] = L[i] 
            i+= 1
            k+= 1
    
        while j < len(R): 
            arr[k] = R[j] 
            j+= 1
            k+= 1

# Code to print the list 
def printList(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        print(arr[i], end =" ")
    print() 

# driver code to test the above code 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    #arr = [12, 11, 13, 5, 6, 7]
    arr = [38, 27, 43, 3, 9, 82, 10]
    print ("Given array is", end ="\n") 
    printList(arr) 
    mergeSort(arr) 
    print("Sorted array is: ", end ="\n") 
    printList(arr) 

# This code is contributed by Mayank Khanna
```

The function mergeSort() is called from within itself as commented above, is this good practice? I was under the impression it could cause errors.

Comment: Yes, recursion is completely normal and acceptable. Variables are kept on a stack.

Comment: A good and simple example of recursion is to find a factorial of a number. Using recursion sometimes is required and it's a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR It's usually fine, but for some inputs can be very dangerous.

The given `mergeSort` function, calls itself - and this phenomenon called [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).

***What is Recursion***

1. A common way of solving problems, where solution depends on solutions to smaller instances of the same problem; such as traversing binary trees.
2. Each recursive call the function parameters are pushed into the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), and each call has its own local variables.
3. Recursion can cause vulnerabilities, for example [DNS open recursion](https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerabilities/web/dns-open-recursion/).
4. If misused either by not defining a stop-condition or by handling input that causes a tremendous amount of recursive calls, a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) will occur (which means that the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) has been used to its maximum).
5. [Any recursive solution can be converted to an iterative solution (solution using loops)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931762/can-every-recursion-be-converted-into-iteration/933979)

***To Sum Up***

1. Recursion is safe when the function invoked for a reasonable amount of time.
2. Python's default recursion limit is `1000`, so function cannot call itself more than `1000` times.

You can validate it with `getrecursionlimit`:

```
import sys
print(sys.getrecursionlimit())
```

And change it with [`setrecursionlimit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit):

```
new_recursion_limit = 1500
sys.setrecursionlimit(new_recursion_limit)
```

3. Recursion may, and will, cause vulnerabilities, and preferably be avoided when handling user input - in favor of iterative solution.

P.S.

Now you know what our site is named after too!

Comment: `set_recursion_limit` is the naive way to increase recursion limit in Python

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem in calling a function within itself, but you just have to be extra careful about going into an infinite loop. General good practices about doing this would be only calling the function at its end (so you reduce chances of mixing up variables' values) and having some sort of `if` statement, or something in that sense, to provide a way out.